# How do I follow-up a Parallel.ForEach on completion?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I want to take a set of objects and run a routine on all of them. The order doesn't matter and they are each independent operations, so I thought I would call [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx).[ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) on the collection. But I want to follow-up the whole thing once complete.

Where is the [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) equivalent or an overload of [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) that takes another action/Task to run on completion? Am I stuck polling the [ParallelLoopResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult.aspx).[IsCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult.iscompleted.aspx) value until it comes back true?

The [ContinueWhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenall.aspx) method always expects an array of Tasks. Should I instead project the set of objects into new Tasks for each? How would I then start an array of Tasks all at once and in parallel?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068971/how-to-run-a-set-of-functions-in-parallel-and-wait-for-the-results-upon-completio) is similar, but concerns the older 3.5 TPL Extensions I believe.  I'm open to solutions outside of the Task Parallel Library if need be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` blocks until it's finished, so you can just do whatever you need to after the method call.

Comment: So I should start a Parallel.ForEach inside a parent Task in order to avoid running it on the UI thread? And then ContinueWith on the parent Task?

Comment: @Yadyn: Potentially, yes. That should work. Of course in C# 5 it'll be a lot easier with async and await...

Comment: @JonSkeet have the behaviour changed in 4.5? Because when I start Parallel.Foreach, it does some part of the work (or sometimes nothing), then moves on to execute code that's written after a loop, then resumes its work

Comment: @chester89: I would have to see that in action to explain it. I suggest you ask a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet fair enough