# Using Parallel.ForEach Create multiple requests in parallel and put them in the list

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, restsharp, parallel.foreach

So I had to create dozens of API requests and get json to make it an object and put it in a list.
I also wanted the requests to be parallel because I do not care about the order in which the objects enter the list.

```
  public ConcurrentBag<myModel> GetlistOfDstAsync()
  {
   var req = new RequestGenerator();
   var InitializedObjects = req.GetInitializedObjects();
   var myList = new ConcurrentBag<myModel>();

   Parallel.ForEach(InitializedObjects, async item =>
            {
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("resource",Method.GET);
            request.AddQueryParameter("key", item.valueOne);
            request.AddQueryParameter("key", item.valueTwo);


            var results = await GetAsync<myModel>(request);

            myList.Add(results);
            });

   return myList;
   }
```

What creates a new problem, I do not understand how to put them in the list and it seems I do not use a solution that exists in a form `ConcurrentBag`

Is my assumption correct and I implement it wrong or should I use another solution?

Comment: You can convert a ConcurrentBag to a list using `ToList()`. Does that address the question?

Comment: HTTP requests **do not** require use of `Parallel` to run concurrently. It has buil in `Task` support (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779206/how-to-use-restsharp-with-async-await) so you should use `Task.WhenAll` on that.

Comment: If you really want to persist with using `Parallel`, use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564465/how-do-you-use-asparallel-with-the-async-and-await-keywords and use `ToList` at the end.

Comment: can you show me the way master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also wanted the requests to be parallel

What you actually want is *concurrent* requests. `Parallel` does not work as expected with `async`.

To do asynchronous concurrency, you *start* each request but do not `await` the tasks yet. Then, you can `await` all the tasks together and get the responses using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task<myModel[]> GetlistOfDstAsync()
{
  var req = new RequestGenerator();
  var InitializedObjects = req.GetInitializedObjects();
  var tasks = InitializedObject.Select(async item =>
  {
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("resource",Method.GET);
    request.AddQueryParameter("key", item.valueOne);
    request.AddQueryParameter("key", item.valueTwo);
    return await GetAsync<myModel>(request);
  }).ToList();

  var results = await TaskWhenAll(tasks);
  return results;
}
```