# How to await an async UI method from a different thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

**How can I *elegantly* tell my application that it should await the result of some async (`Ask()`) method not on its current (`Game`) thread but on a different (`UI`) thread instead?**

I've got a Forms application with two threads

- the obligatory `UI Thread`, which runs the user interface
- and a second `Game Thread`, that runs in a sort of infinite loop, waiting for input actions and rendering the game view at a more or less constant framerate.

The user interface consists of two forms:

- a simple `MainForm` with a `Create Cube` button, a `Create Sphere` button and a rendering view
- and a custom `ChoiceForm` that asks the user to choose between `Sharp Corners` and `Rounded Corners` using two according buttons.

When the user clicks on the `Create Cube` button, the `UI Thread` will handle this click event and (synchronously) queue a new `()=>Game.Create<Cube>()` action to be processed by the `Game Thread`.

The `Game Thread` will fetch this action when it is processing another frame and check if the user wanted to create a `Cube` or a `Sphere`. And if the user requested a `Cube` it should ask the user using the second form about the desired shape for the cube corners.

The problem is, that neither the `UI` nor the `Game` thread should be blocked while waiting for the user decision. Because of this the `Task Game.Create<T>(...)` method and the `Task<CornerChoice> ChoiceForm.Ask()`methods are declared as async. The `Game Thread` will await the result of the `Create<T>()` method, which in its turn should await the result of the `Ask()` method on the UI thread (because the `ChoiceForm` is created and displayed right inside of that method).

If this all would happen on a single `UI Thread` life would be relatively easy and the `Create` method would look like this:

```
public class Game
{
    private async Task Create<IShape>()
    {
        CornerChoice choice = await ChoiceForm.Ask();
        ...
    }
}
```

After some trial and error I came up with the following (actually working) solution, but it seem to hurt me somewhere inside each time I look at it closely (especially the `Task<Task<CornerChoice>>` part in the `Create` method):

```
public enum CornerChoice {...}

public class ChoiceForm
{
    public static Task<CornerChoice> Ask()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class MainForm
{
    private readonly Game _game;

    public MainForm()
    {
        _game = new Game(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
    ...
}

public class Game
{
    private readonly TaskScheduler _uiScheduler;

    public Game(TaskScheduler uiScheduler)
    {
        _uiScheduler = uiScheduler;
    }

    private async Task Create<IShape>()
    {
        ...
        Task<CornerChoice> task = await Task<Task<CornerChoice>>.Factory.StartNew(
            async () => await ChoiceForm.Ask(),
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiScheduler);
        CornerChoice choice = await task;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a better way to await a Task on a different thread than the one that I worked out using await await Task<Task<T>>?

Comment: Why would the game need to know anything at all about the UI? If you want it to create a `Shape`, you need to tell him (your `Game` object) after the user has told you if he wants a cube or a sphere.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The actual application is not a game but an application with a conventional user interface and one or more rendering views that are run by the second thread. Because it is not always immediately clear, which further steps will be required to fulfill such a "Create" request, the second (viewport) thread needs a possibility to present the user with additional questions and await their result without to interrupt the rendering process.

Comment: Can you try replacing Task.Factory.StartNew with Task.Run, in that case you do not need to create a type like Task<Task<CornerChoice>>, I will paste a simple example I have created below. It may not answer your complete question, but is an attempt to take care of sub part of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a probably related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15428604/993388) and Stephen Dougs blog post [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) linked by Stephen Cleary and discussing this question with Mrinal Kamboj I was led to the conclusion that the `Task.Run` method is sort of a wrapper around `TaskFactory.StartNew` for the common cases. So for my not-so-common case I decided to sweep the pain-causing stuff into an extension method to make the invocation look like following:

```
private async Task Create<IShape>()
{
    ...
    CornerChoice choice = await _uiScheduler.Run(ChoiceForm.Ask);
    ...
}
```

With the according extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionsForTaskScheduler
{
    public static async Task<T> Run<T>(this TaskScheduler scheduler,
        Func<Task<T>> scheduledTask)
    {
        return await await Task<Task<T>>.Factory.StartNew(scheduledTask,
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);
    }
}
```

It seems that it was also not necessary to declare the `() => ChoiceForm.Ask()` lambda as `async`.

Comment: This is a valid implementation, but a less-coupled solution would be to have the UI expose a "service" like IAskChoice rather than have the background thread aware of `ChoiceForm` or task schedulers (or any UI at all).