# How to throttle multiple asynchronous tasks?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have some code of the following form:

```
static async Task DoSomething(int n) 
{
  ...
}

static void RunThreads(int totalThreads, int throttle) 
{
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  for (var n = 0; n < totalThreads; n++)
  {
    var task = DoSomething(n);
    tasks.Add(task);
  }
  Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait(); // all threads must complete
}
```

Trouble is, if I don't throttle the threads, things start falling apart.  Now, I want to launch a maximum of `throttle` threads, and only start the new thread when an old one is complete.  I've tried a few approaches and none so far has worked.  Problems I have encountered include:

- The `tasks` collection must be fully populated with all tasks, whether active or awaiting execution, otherwise the final `.Wait()` call only looks at the threads that it started with.
- Chaining the execution seems to require use of `Task.Run()` or the like.  But I need a reference to each task from the outset, and instantiating a task seems to kick it off automatically, which is what I don't want.

How to do this?

Comment: Maybe add a amount of `throttle` tasks to the list and run them each time.

Comment: @CliveDM I don't have a clear picture of what you mean.  Perhaps post an answer with some sample code?

Comment: http://blog.danskingdom.com/tag/c-task-thread-throttle-limit-maximum-simultaneous-concurrent-parallel/

Comment: Related: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, abstract away from threads. Especially since your operation is asynchronous, you shouldn't be thinking about "threads" at all. In the asynchronous world, you have tasks, and you can have a *huge* number of tasks compared to threads.

Throttling asynchronous code can be done using `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
static async Task DoSomething(int n);

static void RunConcurrently(int total, int throttle) 
{
  var mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(throttle);
  var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, total).Select(async item =>
  {
    await mutex.WaitAsync();
    try { await DoSomething(item); }
    finally { mutex.Release(); }
  });
  Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
}
```

Comment: Why RunConcurrently is synchronous? I mean, in that case we can simply use Parallel.For and inside it we can call DoSomething(item).Result

Comment: It's synchronous because the op's code was synchronous. The purpose of this answer is to illustrate asynchronous throttling.

Answer (score 17):

The simplest option IMO is to use TPL Dataflow. You just create an `ActionBLock`, limit it by the desired parallelism and start posting items into it. It makes sure to only run a certain amount of tasks at the same time, and when a task completes, it starts executing the next item:

```
async Task RunAsync(int totalThreads, int throttle) 
{
    var block = new ActionBlock<int>(
        DoSomething,
        new ExecutionDataFlowOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = throttle });

    for (var n = 0; n < totalThreads; n++)
    {
        block.Post(n);
    }

    block.Complete();
    await block.Completion;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, you can start tasks limited number of tasks mentioned by `throttle` parameter and wait for them to finish before starting next..

To wait for all started tasks to complete before starting new tasks, use the following implementation.

```
static async Task RunThreads(int totalThreads, int throttle)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var n = 0; n < totalThreads; n++)
    {
        var task = DoSomething(n);
        tasks.Add(task);

        if (tasks.Count == throttle)
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            tasks.Clear();
        }
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // wait for remaining
}
```

To add tasks as on when it is completed you can use the following code

```
static async Task RunThreads(int totalThreads, int throttle)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var n = 0; n < totalThreads; n++)
    {
        var task = DoSomething(n);
        tasks.Add(task);

        if (tasks.Count == throttle)
        {
            var completed = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
            tasks.Remove(completed);
        }
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // all threads must complete
}
```

Comment: @ShaulBehr Yep, that's it.

Comment: Close, except that this will wait for each batch to complete, rather than immediately starting a new thread each time one thread completes.

Comment: @ShaulBehr Updated my answer(not tested though). See if that helps.

Answer (score 7):

Stephen Toub gives the following example for throttling in his [The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) document.

```
const int CONCURRENCY_LEVEL = 15;
Uri [] urls = …;
int nextIndex = 0;
var imageTasks = new List<Task<Bitmap>>();
while(nextIndex < CONCURRENCY_LEVEL && nextIndex < urls.Length)
{
    imageTasks.Add(GetBitmapAsync(urls[nextIndex]));
    nextIndex++;
}

while(imageTasks.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        Task<Bitmap> imageTask = await Task.WhenAny(imageTasks);
        imageTasks.Remove(imageTask);

        Bitmap image = await imageTask;
        panel.AddImage(image);
    }
    catch(Exception exc) { Log(exc); }

    if (nextIndex < urls.Length)
    {
        imageTasks.Add(GetBitmapAsync(urls[nextIndex]));
        nextIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (Rx) - NuGet "Rx-Main" - has this problem sorted very nicely.

Just do this:

```
static void RunThreads(int totalThreads, int throttle) 
{
    Observable
        .Range(0, totalThreads)
        .Select(n => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomething(n)))
        .Merge(throttle)
        .Wait();
}
```

Job done.

Answer (score 6):

.NET 6 introduces `Parallel.ForEachAsync`. You could rewrite your code like this:

```
static async ValueTask DoSomething(int n)
{
    ...
}

static Task RunThreads(int totalThreads, int throttle)
    => Parallel.ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(0, totalThreads), new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = throttle }, (i, _) => DoSomething(i));
```

Notes:

- I had to change the return type of your `DoSomething` function from `Task` to `ValueTask`.
- You probably want to avoid the `.Wait()` call, so I made the `RunThreads` method async.
- It is not obvious from your example why you need access to the individual tasks. This code does not give you access to the tasks, but might still be helpful in many cases.

Comment: Doesn't this launch new threads though using `Task.Run`? Or does it only throttle the `awaits` like a throttled version of `Task.WhenAll`?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some extension method variations to build on Sriram Sakthivel answer.

In the usage example, calls to `DoSomething` are being wrapped in an explicitly cast closure to allow passing arguments.

```
public static async Task RunMyThrottledTasks()
{
    var myArgsSource = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    await myArgsSource
        .Select(a => (Func<Task<object>>)(() => DoSomething(a)))
        .Throttle(2);
}

public static async Task<object> DoSomething(int arg)
{
    // Await some async calls that need arg..
    // ..then return result async Task..
    return new object();
}

public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Throttle<T>(IEnumerable<Func<Task<T>>> toRun, int throttleTo)
{
    var running = new List<Task<T>>(throttleTo);
    var completed = new List<Task<T>>(toRun.Count());
    foreach(var taskToRun in toRun)
    {
        running.Add(taskToRun());
        if(running.Count == throttleTo)
        {
            var comTask = await Task.WhenAny(running);
            running.Remove(comTask);
            completed.Add(comTask);
        }
    }
    return completed.Select(t => t.Result);
}

public static async Task Throttle(this IEnumerable<Func<Task>> toRun, int throttleTo)
{
    var running = new List<Task>(throttleTo);
    foreach(var taskToRun in toRun)
    {
        running.Add(taskToRun());
        if(running.Count == throttleTo)
        {
            var comTask = await Task.WhenAny(running);
            running.Remove(comTask);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a custom task scheduler. You can derive a class from System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler and implement two major functions `GetScheduledTasks()`, `QueueTask()`, along with other functions to gain complete control over throttling tasks. Here is a well documented example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0

Comment: There is no need to implement a `TaskScheduler` by hand. You could just use a [`ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.ConcurrentScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair.concurrentscheduler). But the bigger problem is that `TaskScheduler`s [are completely unable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428604/how-to-run-a-task-on-a-custom-taskscheduler-using-await/57702536#57702536) to throttle asynchronous operations.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually emulate the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` method introduced as part of .NET 6. In order to emulate the same you can use the following code.

```cs
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int maxDegreeOfParallelism, Func<T, Task> body) {
    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(maxDegreeOfParallelism)
        select Task.Run(async delegate {
            using (partition)
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                    await body(partition.Current);
        }));
}
```

Comment: This solution is flawed for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634376/running-async-methods-in-parallel/#comment111638079_52973907), hence my downvote.

Comment: Do you suggest using a SemaphoreSlim instead @TheodorZoulias?

Comment: Yes, the `SemaphoreSlim` is a solid solution, and communicates clearly its intentions.