# C# LanguageExt - combine multiple async calls into one grouped call

Tags: c#, functional-programming, monads, language-ext

I have a method that looks up an item asynchronously from a datastore;

```cs
class MyThing {}
Task<Try<MyThing>> GetThing(int thingId) {...}
```

I want to look up multiple items from the datastore, and wrote a new method to do this. I also wrote a helper method that will take multiple `Try<T>` and combine their results into a single `Try<IEnumerable<T>>`.

```cs
public static class TryExtensions
{
    Try<IEnumerable<T>> Collapse<T>(this IEnumerable<Try<T>> items)
    {
        var failures = items.Fails().ToArray();
        return failures.Any() ?
            Try<IEnumerable<T>>(new AggregateException(failures)) :
            Try(items.Select(i => i.Succ(a => a).Fail(Enumerable.Empty<T>())));
    }
}

async Task<Try<MyThing[]>> GetThings(IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
    var results = new List<Try<Things>>();

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        var thing = await GetThing(id);
        results.Add(thing);
    }

    return results.Collapse().Map(p => p.ToArray());
}
```

Another way to do it would be like this;

```cs
async Task<Try<MyThing[]>> GetThings(IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
    var tasks = ids.Select(async id => await GetThing(id)).ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return tasks.Select(t => t.Result).Collapse().Map(p => p.ToArray());
}
```

The problem with this is that all the tasks will run in parallel and I don't want to hammer my datastore with lots of parallel requests. What I really want is to make my code functional, using monadic principles and features of `LanguageExt`. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

---

### Update

Thanks for the suggestion @MatthewWatson, this is what it looks like with the `SemaphoreSlim`;

```cs
async Task<Try<MyThing[]>> GetThings(IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
    var mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    var results = ids.Select(async id =>
    {
        await mutex.WaitAsync();
        try { return await GetThing(id); }
        finally { mutex.Release(); }
    }).ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return tasks.Select(t => t.Result).Collapse().Map(Enumerable.ToArray);
    return results.Collapse().Map(p => p.ToArray());
}
```

Problem is, this is still not very monadic / functional, and ends up with more lines of code than my original code with a `foreach` block.

Comment: You could use `SemaphoreSlim` to throttle, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/a/57557324/106159

Comment: Seems a fairly arbitrary requirement to have "fewer" lines of code.  What is the aim of this?  How many lines of code is acceptable?

Comment: Sorry @TimRutter. My requirement was to make my code 'functional', i.e. using combinations of `Map`, `Match`, `Bind`, etc. In any regard, I think the version using a foreach is 'neater' (regardless of the number of lines), but that is just my opinion.

Comment: Why do you think (for my understanding; not that familiar with functional programming) that the code in your update is not functional?  Functional means it doesn't change state and doesn't monadic just mean it takes one parameter?

Comment: I somehow believed that I could achieve the above by doing `return ids.Select(dosomething).Map(dosomethingelse).Bind(athirdthing);` without having to write any loops. The community says that loops are not necessary in functional programming - https://qr.ae/pNC6fQ

Comment: ok yes i see what you mean now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Another way" you almost achieved your goal when you called:

`var tasks = ids.Select(async id => await GetThing(id)).ToArray();`

Except that Tasks doesn't run **sequentially** so you will end up with many queries hitting your datastore, which is caused by `.ToArray()` and `Task.WhenAll`. Once you called `.ToArray()` it allocated and started the Tasks already, so if you can "tolerate" one `foreach` to achieve the sequential tasks running, like this:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task RunSequentially<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks) await task;
    }
}
```

> Despite that running a "loop" of queries is not a quite good practice
> in general, unless you have in some background service and some
> special scenario, leveraging this to the Database engine through
> `WHERE thingId IN (...)` *in general* is a better option. Even you
> have big amount of thingIds we can slice it into small 10s, 100s.. to
> narrow the `WHERE IN` footprint.

Back to our `RunSequentially`, I **would** like to make it more functional like this for example:

```
tasks.ToList().ForEach(async task => await task);
```

But sadly this will still run kinda "Parallel" tasks.

So the final usage should be:

```
async Task<Try<MyThing[]>> GetThings(IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
    var tasks = ids.Select(id => GetThing(id));// remember don't use .ToArray or ToList...
    await tasks.RunSequentially();
    return tasks.Select(t => t.Result).Collapse().Map(p => p.ToArray());
}
```

### Another overkill functional solution is to get *Lazy* in a *Queue* *recursively* !!

Instead `GetThing`, get a Lazy one `GetLazyThing` that returns `Lazy<Task<Try<MyThing>>>` simply by wrapping `GetThing`:

```
new Lazy<Task<Try<MyThing>>>(() => GetThing(id))
```

Now using couple extensions/functions:

```
public static async Task RecRunSequentially<T>(this IEnumerable<Lazy<Task<T>>> tasks)
{
    var queue = tasks.EnqueueAll();
    await RunQueue(queue);
}

public static Queue<T> EnqueueAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    var queue = new Queue<T>();
    list.ToList().ForEach(m => queue.Enqueue(m));
    return queue;
}

public static async Task RunQueue<T>(Queue<Lazy<Task<T>>> queue)
{
    if (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var task = queue.Dequeue();
        await task.Value; // this unwraps the Lazy object content
        await RunQueue(queue);
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
var lazyTasks = ids.Select(id => GetLazyThing(id));
await lazyTasks.RecRunSequentially();
// Now collapse and map as you like
```

### Update

However if you don't like the fact that `EnqueueAll` and `RunQueue` are not "pure", we can take the following approach with the same `Lazy` trick

```
public static async Task AwaitSequentially<T>(this Lazy<Task<T>>[] array, int index = 0)
{
    if (array == null || index < 0 || index >= array.Length - 1) return;
    await array[index].Value;
    await AwaitSequentially(array, index + 1); // ++index is not pure :)
}
```

Now:

```
var lazyTasks = ids.Select(id => GetLazyThing(id));
await tasks.ToArray().AwaitSequentially();
// Now collapse and map as you like
```

Comment: That’s exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Nice work.