# Custom TaskFactory does not use custom SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext

**Note: this is under Unity3D**

I need to run an inner task using a custom synchronization context, like the following:

- outer task -> on default scheduler

  - inner task -> on custom scheduler with custom synchronization context

This is because some objects in inner task can only be created on a specific thread that the custom synchronization context will post to, on the other hand, I want the outer task to be run normally, i.e. `ThreadPool` or whatever `Task.Run` uses.

**Following advice from this question:**

[How to run a Task on a custom TaskScheduler using await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428604/how-to-run-a-task-on-a-custom-taskscheduler-using-await)

Unfortunately, that doesn't work, the synchronization context is still the default one:

```
OUTER JOB: 'null'
0
        INNER JOB: 'null' <------------- this context should not be the default one
        0,      1,      2,      3,      4,
1
        INNER JOB: 'null'
        0,      1,      2,      3,      4,
2
        INNER JOB: 'null'
        0,      1,      2,      3,      4,
Done, press any key to exit
```

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal static class Program
{
    private static TaskFactory CustomFactory { get; set; }

    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create a custom task factory with a custom synchronization context,
        // and make sure to restore initial context after it's been created

        var initial = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new CustomSynchronizationContext());

        CustomFactory = new TaskFactory(
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        );

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(initial);


        // now do some work on initial context

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"OUTER JOB: {GetCurrentContext()}");

            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                await Task.Delay(100);

                // now do some work on custom context
                await RunOnCustomScheduler(DoSpecialWork);
            }
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Done, press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void DoSpecialWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\tINNER JOB: {GetCurrentContext()}"); // TODO wrong context

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            Console.Write($"\t{i}, ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static Task RunOnCustomScheduler(Action action)
    {
        return CustomFactory.StartNew(action);
    }

    private static string GetCurrentContext()
    {
        return SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString() ?? "'null'";
    }
}

public class CustomSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
}
```

When I debug, I can see that the custom factory indeed has the custom scheduler with a custom context, but in practice it doesn't work however.

**Question:**

How can I get my custom scheduler to use the custom context it's been created from?

**Final answer:**

I was awaiting a method inside thread I wanted to avoid working in, wrapping that stuff in `await Task.Run` (plus some details left out for brevity) fixed it. Now I can run my long task outside Unity thread but still make Unity calls inside it using custom factory approach in question above.

i.e. it was already working but I wasn't using it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CustomSynchronizationContext` is indeed used for running the `DoSpecialWork` method. You can confirm this by overriding the `Post` method of the base class:

```
public class CustomSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"@Post");
        base.Post(d, state);
    }
}
```

Then run your program again and you'll see three *@Post* appearing in the console.

The reason that the [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) is `null` is because this property is associated with the current thread. Here is the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs.html#826929a6f7e9421f):

```
// Get the current SynchronizationContext on the current thread
public static SynchronizationContext Current 
{
    get      
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.GetExecutionContextReader().SynchronizationContext ?? GetThreadLocalContext();
    }
}
```

You could install your `CustomSynchronizationContext` in each thread of the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool), but this is not recommended. It's not required either. In the absence of a `SynchronizationContext.Current` the async continuations are running in the current `TaskScheduler`, and the current `TaskScheduler` inside the `DoSpecialWorkAsync` method is the one that you have created yourself with the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` method, which is associated with your `CustomSynchronizationContext` instance.

Comment: Okay now I understand X) so the problem comes from something else, I need to find out where from.

Comment: @Aybe yeap, all this stuff is good to know but rarely useful. :-)

Comment: Except when you need it :D

Comment: I finally fixed my issue, needed to think out of the box !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that very easily using ReactiveExtensions (nuget System.Reactive):

```
public static Task RunOnCustomScheduler(Action action, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Return(Unit.Default)
        .ObserveOn(scheduler) // switch context
        .Do(_ => action.Invoke()) // do the work
        // .Select(_ => func.Invoke()) // change Action to Func if you want to return stuff.
        //.Select(async _ => await func.Invoke()) // can work with async stuff, though ConfigureAwait may become tricky
        .ToTask();
}
```

You can also pass `SynchronizationContext` instead of IScheduler.

Remember to `ConfigureAwait(false/true)` though when you call this method to configure how you want to continue

Comment: Okay I need to test and see if that library works well with Unity3d and I'll come back.

Comment: You didn't mention Unity :P but I think it should work, and if not, there should be Unity specific implementations of Rx