# How do I manage locks when implementing parallel task invocations with Task.WhenAll and max degree of parallelism?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, locking, task

I came up with the following code which calls a database paging function repeatedly with a page size of 5 and for each item in a page executes a function in parallel with a max concurrency of 4. It looks like its working so far but I'm unsure if I need to use locking to enclose the `parallelInvocationTasks.Remove(completedTask);` line and `Task.WhenAll(parallelInvocationTasks.ToArray());` So do I need to use locking here and do you see any other improvements?

Here's the code

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
            Func<int, int, CancellationToken, Task<IList<string>>> getNextPageFunction = GetNextPageFromDatabase;
            await getNextPageFunction.ForEachParallel(4, 5, new CancellationToken(), async (item) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item} started");
                //simulate processing
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine($"{item} ended");
            });
            
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        private static async Task<IList<string>> GetNextPageFromDatabase(
            int offset,
            int pageSize,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //simulate i/o and database paging
            await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);
            var pageData = new List<string>();
            
            //simulate just 4 pages
            if (offset >= pageSize * 3)
            {
                return pageData;
            }

            for (var i = 1; i <= pageSize; i++)
            {
                string nextItem = $"Item {i + offset}";
                pageData.Add(nextItem);
            }

            return pageData;
        } 
    }
}
```

PagingExtensions.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public static class PagingExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<int> ForEachParallel<TItem>(
            this Func<int, int, CancellationToken, Task<IList<TItem>>> getNextPageFunction,
            int concurrency,
            int pageSize,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            Func<TItem, Task> forEachFunction)
        {
            var enumeratedCount = 0;
            if (getNextPageFunction == null || forEachFunction == null)
            {
                return enumeratedCount;
            }

            var offset = 0;
            using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(concurrency))
            {
                IList<Task> parallelInvocationTasks = new List<Task>();
                IList<TItem> items;
                
                do
                {
                    items = await getNextPageFunction(offset, pageSize, cancellationToken) ?? new List<TItem>();
                    foreach (TItem item in items)
                    {
                        await semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
                        Task forEachFunctionTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    await forEachFunction(item);
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    // ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure
                                    // This is safe as long as Task.WhenAll is called before the using semaphore
                                    // enclosure ends
                                    semaphore.Release();
                                }
                            }, cancellationToken)
                            .Unwrap();

                        parallelInvocationTasks.Add(forEachFunctionTask);
                        
#pragma warning disable 4014
                        forEachFunctionTask.ContinueWith((completedTask) =>
#pragma warning restore 4014
                        {
                            if (completedTask.Exception == null)
                            {
                                //Intention is to release completed tasks during enumeration as they complete
                                //so they can be GCed. This is to ensure the 'parallelInvocationTasks' list does not
                                //grow in an unmanaged manner resulting in a list holding multiple completed tasks
                                //unnecessarily consuming more memory with each added invocation task
                                //Thus the final Task.WhenAll call below will only need to await only faulted tasks
                                //causing it to throw an exception and/or a minimal list of incomplete tasks only
                                parallelInvocationTasks.Remove(completedTask);
                            }
                        }, cancellationToken);

                        enumeratedCount += 1;
                    }
                    
                    offset += pageSize;
                }
                while (items.Count >= pageSize);
                
                await Task.WhenAll(parallelInvocationTasks.ToArray());
            }

            return enumeratedCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intentionally put `await semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);` outside of the task and `semaphore.Release();` inside the task created in `ForEachParallel()`? Normally you would place these so they execute on the same thread(task)

Comment: Why do you not simply use Parallel.Foreach ? As far as I can see it has all the features you require, and should be guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: `parallelInvocationTasks.Remove(completedTask);` should absolutely have a `lock`, any time you **might** modify a collection, even one captured in a method like this, you should lock it while modifying it.

Comment: `List<T>.ToArray` is an [O(n) operation per MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=net-5.0#remarks), it's safe to say using the extension would iterate and read the values sequentially, therefor you use lock the `await Task.WhenAll(parallelInvocationTasks.ToArray());` since there is a remote chance the collection may change during `ToArray`'s execution.

Comment: Yes I was betting on the ToArray to work as @DekuDesu explained. I see now that locking that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @JonasH Parallel.ForEach is made for CPU-intensive computations and doesn't recognize async methods. It doesn't await them AFAIK

Comment: @DekuDesu awaiting the semaphore before creating the task is a valid technique. It is more complex than awaiting it inside the task, but also more efficient. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391377/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-number-of-parallel-tasks-globally-in-an-asp-net-web/66443140#66443140) answer for more details.

Comment: Having googled this for a bit I'm leaning more towards TPL DataFlow and ActionBlocks. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11565317/454378

Comment: It absolutely is! I was just clarifying. I was there when you wrote it the first time :P. I just find it important with semaphores, if that technique is used intentionally - as it is one of the few ways you can lead mis-matched releases if poorly implemented.

Comment: Harindaka yes, with the TPL Dataflow you'll get better exception handling behavior. Basically a failed task will cause the timely failure of the whole parallel loop, instead of waiting for all other tasks to complete just to receive this error at the end. [I have posted myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach/65251949#65251949) some simple implementations of a `ForEachAsync` method that is based on TPL Dataflow, in the linked question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I formulated the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67635290/454378) which I believe gets the job done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on the comments above and a little bit more research I arrived at this answer which gets the work done without all the complexity of having to write custom code to manage concurrency. It uses ActionBlock from TPL DataFlow

PagingExtensions.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public static class PagingExtensions
    {
        public delegate Task<IList<TItem>> GetNextPageDelegate<TItem>(
            int offset,
            int pageSize,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken);

        public static async Task<int> EnumerateParallel<TItem>(
            this GetNextPageDelegate<TItem> getNextPageFunction,
            int maxDegreeOfParallelism,
            int pageSize,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            Func<TItem, Task> forEachFunction)
        {
            var enumeratedCount = 0;
            if (getNextPageFunction == null || forEachFunction == null)
            {
                return enumeratedCount;
            }

            var offset = 0;
            var forEachFunctionBlock = new ActionBlock<TItem>(forEachFunction, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                BoundedCapacity = pageSize > maxDegreeOfParallelism ? pageSize : maxDegreeOfParallelism,
                EnsureOrdered = false,
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism,
                CancellationToken = cancellationToken
            });

            IList<TItem> items;

            do
            {
                items = await getNextPageFunction(offset, pageSize, cancellationToken) ?? new List<TItem>();
                foreach (TItem item in items)
                {
                    await forEachFunctionBlock.SendAsync(item, cancellationToken);
                    enumeratedCount += 1;
                }

                offset += pageSize;
            }
            while (items.Count >= pageSize);

            forEachFunctionBlock.Complete();
            await forEachFunctionBlock.Completion;

            return enumeratedCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Just be aware that the `BoundedCapacity` option can also limit to the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. In case the `BoundedCapacity` is smaller than the configured `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, the effective `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` will be reduced to the `BoundedCapacity` value.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks. Edited the answer to set the larger value