# Running parallel async tasks and return result in .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, task-parallel-library, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi Recently i was working in .net core web api project which is downloading files from external api.
In this .net core api recently found some issues while the no of files is more say more than 100. API is downloading max of 50 files and skipping others. WebAPI is deployed on AWS Lambda and timeout is 15mnts.

Actually the operation is timing out due to the long download process

```
public async Task<bool> DownloadAttachmentsAsync(List<DownloadAttachment> downloadAttachment)
        {
            try
            {
                bool DownloadFlag = false;

                foreach (DownloadAttachment downloadAttachment in downloadAttachments)
                {
                    DownloadFlag = await DownloadAttachment(downloadAttachment.id);

                    //update the download status in database
                    if(DownloadFlag)
                    {
                      bool UpdateFlag = await _DocumentService.UpdateDownloadStatus(downloadAttachment.id);

                      if (UpdateFlag)
                      {
                        await DeleteAttachment(downloadAttachment.id);
                      }
                   }
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ext)
            {
                log.Error(ext, "Error in Saving attachment {attachemntId}",downloadAttachment.id);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Document service code

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateAttachmentDownloadStatus(string AttachmentID)
        {
            return await _documentRepository.UpdateAttachmentDownloadStatus(AttachmentID);
        }
```

And DB update code

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateAttachmentDownloadStatus(string AttachmentID)
        {
            using (var db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.Value))
            {
                var Result = 0; bool SuccessFlag = false;
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("@pm_AttachmentID", AttachmentID);               
                parameters.Add("@pm_Result", Result, System.Data.DbType.Int32, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
                var result = await db.ExecuteAsync("[Loan].[UpdateDownloadStatus]", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                Result = parameters.Get<int>("@pm_Result");
                if (Result > 0) { SuccessFlag = true; }
                return SuccessFlag;
            }
        }
```

How can i move this async task to run parallel ? and get the result? i tried following code

```
var task = Task.Run(() => DownloadAttachment( downloadAttachment.id));
bool result = task.Result;
```

Is this approach is fine? how can improve the performance? how to get the result from each parallel task and update to DB and delete based on success flag? Or this error is due to AWS timeout?

Please help

Comment: What is `_DocumentService`? It is thread safe?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv : that is db operation part where updating the file download flag in database

Comment: So you cannot do that in parallel. You have to create new DbContext for each task.

Comment: You *can* make an HTTP call and save to the database asynchronously, and it's a LOT easier than what you tried. That's the job of `async/await`, not `Task.Run`. There's no point in starting task that starts an async operation only to block it. And then block the task itself

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Also, why you call `Task.Run` in Controller and why you get `Task.Result`? You have to to use `await`.

Comment: @athu you haven't provided the code for `DownloadAttachment`, `UpdateDownloadStatus` or `DeleteAttachment` though. If that code has threading issues, or uses database connections and contexts inappropriately, you'll run into problems

Comment: i will update the same

Comment: If `DownloadAttachment` is already asynchronous, what's the point of `Task.Run(() => DownloadAttachment( downloadAttachment.id)).Result`? If that even worked, it would still start and *block* the same operation. Right now though, it just returns the very same task returned by `DownloadAttachment`. If you wanted to start multiple `DownloadAttachment` calls, you could use eg `var tasks=downloadAttachments.Select(att=>DownladAttachment(att.Id));`. That would start all of them at once though, which may not be what you want

Comment: As a side note, although there is no official convention for naming local variables is C#, it is [generally preferable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/naming-convention-of-variables-in-c-programming-language) to use camelCase for them. `bool downloadFlag` is preferrable to `bool DownloadFlag` in the eyes of most C# developers. Also defining and reusing the same variable for all download attachments, and initializing it in an arbitrary value (`false`), is susceptible to introducing bugs. It's better to define this variable inside the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extracted the code that handles individual files to a separate method :

```
private async Task DownloadSingleAttachment(DownloadAttachment attachment)
{
    try
    {
        var download = await DownloadAttachment(downloadAttachment.id);
        if(download)
        {
            var update = await _DocumentService.UpdateDownloadStatus(downloadAttachment.id);
            if (update)
            {
                await DeleteAttachment(downloadAttachment.id);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(....)
    {
    ....
    }
}

public async Task<bool> DownloadAttachmentsAsync(List<DownloadAttachment> downloadAttachment)
{
    try
    {
      foreach (var attachment in downloadAttachments)
      {
          await DownloadSingleAttachment(attachment);
      }
    }
    ....
}
```

It would be easy to start all downloads at once, although not very efficient :

```
public async Task<bool> DownloadAttachmentsAsync(List<DownloadAttachment> downloadAttachment)
{

    try
    {
        //Start all of them
        var tasks=downloadAttachments.Select(att=>DownloadSingleAttachment(att));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    ....
}
```

This isn't very efficient because external services hate lots of concurrent calls from a single source as you do, and almost certainly impose throttling. The database doesn't like lots of concurrent calls either, because *in all database products* concurrent calls lead to blocking one way or another. Even in databases that use multiversioning, this comes with an overhead.

**Using Dataflow classes - Single block**

One easy way to fix this is to use .NET's [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) classes to break the operation into a pipeline of steps, and execute each one with a different number of concurrent tasks.

We could put the entire operation into a single block, but that could cause problems if the update and delete operations aren't thread-safe :

```
var dlOptions= new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
};

var downloader=new ActionBlock<DownloadAttachment>(async att=>{
    await DownloadSingleAttachment(att);
},dlOptions);

foreach (var attachment in downloadAttachments)
{
    await downloader.SendAsync(attachement.id);
}

downloader.Complete();
await downloader.Completion;
```

**Dataflow - Multiple steps**

To avoid possible thread issues, the rest of the methods can go to their own blocks. They could both go into one `ActionBlock` that calls both `Update` and `Delete`, or they could go into separate blocks if the methods talk to different services with different concurrency requirements.

The `downloader` block will execute at most 10 concurrent downloads. By default, each block uses only a single task at a time.

The `updater` and `deleter` blocks have their default DOP=1, which means there's no risk of race conditions as long as they don't try to use eg the same connection at the same time.

```
var downloader=new TransformBlock<string,(string id,bool download)>(
    async id=> {
        var download=await DownloadAttachment(id);
        return (id,download);
},dlOptions);

var updater=new TransformBlock<(string id,bool download),(string id,bool update)>(
    async (id,download)=> {
        if(download)
        {
            var update = await _DocumentService.UpdateDownloadStatus(id);
            return (id,update);
        }
        return (id,false);
});

var deleter=new ActionBlock<(string id,bool update)>(
    async (id,update)=> {
        if(update)
        {
            await DeleteAttachment(id);
        }
});
```

The blocks can be linked into a pipeline now and used. The setting `PropagateCompletion = true` means that as soon as a block is finished processing, it will tell all its connected blocks to finish as well :

```
var linkOptions=new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true};
downloader.LinkTo(updater, linkOptions);
updater.LinkTo(deleter,linkOptions);
```

We can pump data into the head block as long as we need. When we're done, we call the head block's `Complete()` method. As each block finishes processing its data, it will propagate its completion to the next block in the pipeline. We need to  await for the last (tail) block to complete to ensure all the attachments have been processed:

```
foreach (var attachment in downloadAttachments)
{
    await downloader.SendAsync(attachement.id);
}

downloader.Complete();
await deleter.Completion;
```

Each block has an input and (when necessary) an output buffer, which means the "producer" and "consumers" of the messages don't have to be in sync, or even know of each other. All the "producer" needs to know is where to find the head block in a pipeline.

**Throttling and backpressure**

One way to throttle is to use a fixed number of tasks through `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

It's also possible to put a limit to the input buffer, thus blocking previous steps or producers if a block can't process messages fast enough. This can be done simply by setting the [BoundedCapacity option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity?view=net-5.0) for a block:

```
var dlOptions= new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
    BoundedCapacity=20,
};

var updaterOptions= new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    BoundedCapacity=20,
};

...

var downloader=new TransformBlock<...>(...,dlOptions);

var updater=new TransformBlock<...>(...,updaterOptions);
```

No other changes are necessary

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple asynchronous operations you could do something like this:

```
    public async Task RunMultipleAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> myList)
    {
        const int myNumberOfConcurrentOperations = 10;
        var mySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(myNumberOfConcurrentOperations);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach(var myItem in myList)
        {
            await mySemaphore.WaitAsync();
            var task = RunOperation(myItem);
            tasks.Add(task);
            task.ContinueWith(t => mySemaphore.Release());           
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task RunOperation<T>(T myItem)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

Put your code from `DownloadAttachmentsAsync` at the 'Do stuff' comment

This will use a semaphore to limit the number of concurrent operations, since running to many concurrent operations is often a bad idea due to contention. You would need to experiment to find the optimal number of concurrent operations for your use case. Also note that error handling have been omitted to keep the example short.

Comment: Not a fan of using the [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) `ContinueWith` method. It has two problems: it makes the code sensitive to the ambient `TaskScheduler.Current`, and creates fire-and-forget tasks. I would suggest creating the tasks using the eager `.Select` technique discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391377/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-number-of-parallel-tasks-globally-in-an-asp-net-web/66443140#66443140) answer.