# await in Parallel.foreach

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have an async method which will be used in Parallel.Foreach. in the async method there is await for a Task.
However, in the test, seems there are no await behavior, the await Task didn't complete. What's the problem? Below is the code.

```
public void method1()
{
  Ilist<string> testList = new IList<string>(){"1","2","3"};
  Parallel.ForEach(testList, ()=>
  {
       method2();
  });
}
public async void method2()
{
   await Task.run(()=>{  some other codes here });  
}
```

Comment: This is the better worded question for this issue, but a dupe of it has the best answer to it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11565317/176877

Comment: It isn't though: the code example shows that OP's assumptions about async-await and TPL are flawed from the start, in ways that just confuse the  question.

Answer (score 7):

Late to answer, but it looks like you're trying to perform CPU-bound work in parallel, as opposed to performing I/O-bound work asynchronously. `Parallel.ForEach` is taking care of your parallelism, so no need for Task.Run, and `async`/`await` are gaining you nothing here. I'd suggest removing those bits from method2, so the whole thing simplifies to:

```
public void method1()
{
    Ilist<string> testList = new IList<string>(){"1","2","3"};
    Parallel.ForEach(testList, ()=>
    {
        method2();
    });
}
public void method2()
{
    // some other (plain old synchronous) code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`void async` methods are 'fire and forget', and there's no way to wait for them to complete. When `method2` is called in your parallel loop, it returns immediately, so your loop is only ensuring the tasks in `method2` are created before the loop completes.

You can change the return type of `method2` to `Task` which will allow you to wait on the result of the operation e.g.

```
public async Task method()
{
     await Task.Run(() { some other code here });
}
```

which you can wait for in your loop with

```
method2().Wait();
```

although doing this is no better than just running the body of the task in `method2` directly in your foreach delegate.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works. The reason I have to run in method2 because I have to pass different Func to the method1. like create, delete, etc. thanks a lot .