# async foreach with breaking condition

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, system.reactive

I have an interface:

```
public interface IRunner
{
    Task<bool> Run(object o);
}
```

and I have some classes that implement it using async, for example:

```
public class Runner1 : IRunner
{
    public async Task<bool> Run(object o)
    {
        var num  = await SomeExternalAsyncFunc(o);
        return num < 12;
    }
}
```

I need to implement a function that runs on all of the Runners classes in parallel, and returns true only if all of them returned true.
After reading [this](http://www.example.com/) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx) I came up with the following implementation:

```
public class RunMannager
{
    public async Task<bool> Run(ConcurrentBag<IRunner> runnersBag, object o)
    {
        var results = new ConcurrentBag<bool>();
        var tasks = runnersBag.Select(async runner => results.Add(await runner.Run(o)));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        return results.All(result => result);
     }
}
```

However, I have two problems with this implementation:

- I would like that if one of the runners already returned false, the function should not wait for all the others.
- Some of the runners may never return, I would like to use a timeout. If the runner didn't return anything for 10 seconds it will be considered as true was returned.

Maybe using reactive extensions can help?

Comment: I don't know if it exists, but can you reverse the logic? pseudo `!(WhenOne == false)`

Comment: I can,  but how would it help?

Comment: Wouldn't it stop executing when it hits the first false?

Comment: When you make IRunner about a simple delegate instead of a Task, it would become `runnersBag.AsParallel().Any(...)`  Timeouts are not a standard/safe/easy feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version with Rx, with timeouts included. The code as written will run in LINQPad with Rx references added. You can experiment with constructing TrueRunner, FalseRunner and SlowRunner instances in the RunnerFactory method.

Key ideas:

- Use `Select` and `ToObservable()` to start and convert the async Task into an IObservable (see below for a better alternative)
- Use `Timeout()` to add a timeout to each task, which substitutes a true result if a task times out, as requested.
- Use `Where` to filter out `True` results - we only get notified about false outcomes now.
- `Any` returns true if there are any elements in the stream, false otherwise, so flip the result of this in the subsequent `Select` and we are done.

Code:

```
void Main()
{
    Observable.Merge(
        RunnerFactory().Select(x => x.Run(null).ToObservable()
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Observable.Return(true))))
        .Where(res => !res)
        .Any().Select(res => !res)
        .Subscribe(
            res => Console.WriteLine("Result: " + res),
            ex => Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message));                                           
}

public IEnumerable<IRunner> RunnerFactory()
{
    yield return new FalseRunner();
    yield return new SlowRunner();
    yield return new TrueRunner();
}

public interface IRunner
{
    Task<bool> Run(object o);
}

public class Runner : IRunner
{
    protected bool _outcome;

    public Runner(bool outcome)
    {
        _outcome = outcome;
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> Run(object o)
    {
        var result = await Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => _outcome);     
        return result;
    }
}

public class TrueRunner : Runner
{
    public TrueRunner() : base(true) {}
}   

public class FalseRunner : Runner
{
    public FalseRunner() : base(false) {}
}   

public class SlowRunner : Runner
{
    public SlowRunner() : base(false) {}

    public override async Task<bool> Run(object o)
    {
        var result = await Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(
            () => { Thread.Sleep(5000); return _outcome; });        
        return result;
    }
}
```

The OnError handler in there is redundant given the Runner implementations I used; you may want to think about a Catch if you want to suppress Runner errors in your implementation - you can substitute an `IObservable<bool>` much like I did with Timeout.

**EDIT** Another thing I just thought worth mentioning, is that using `Observable.StartAsync` is a better way to start the Task, and will give you support for cancellation as well. Here's some modified code showing how SlowRunner can support cancellation. The token is passed in by `StartAsync` and causes cancellation if the Subscription is disposed. This all happens transparently if `Any` detects an element.

```
void Main()
{
    var runners = GetRunners();     

    Observable.Merge(runners.Select(r => Observable.StartAsync(ct => r.Run(ct, null))
                    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), Observable.Return(true))))
                    .Where(res => !res)
                    .Any().Select(res => !res)
                    .Subscribe(
                        res => Console.WriteLine("Result: " + res));
}

public static IEnumerable<IRunner> GetRunners()
{
    yield return new Runner(false);
    yield return new SlowRunner(true);
}

public interface IRunner
{
    Task<bool> Run(CancellationToken ct, object o);
}

public class Runner : IRunner
{
    protected bool _outcome;

    public Runner(bool outcome)
    {
        _outcome = outcome;
    }

    public async virtual Task<bool> Run(CancellationToken ct, object o)
    {
        var result = await Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => _outcome);
        return result;
    }
}

public class SlowRunner : Runner
{
    public SlowRunner(bool outcome) : base(outcome)
    {
    }

    public async override Task<bool> Run(CancellationToken ct, object o)
    {
        var result = await Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                if(ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");                     
                }
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            };
            return _outcome;
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Parallel.ForEach()`? 
Following code should give you the idea of what I mean.

You could define `CancellationTokenSource`

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.CancellationToken = cancellationToken.Token;
```

Then pass `po` to `Parallel.ForEach`

```
Parallel.ForEach(items, po, item =>
{
   //...
   if(num < 12)
     cancellationToken.Cancel(false);

});

return !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested;
```

Comment: according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach ) Parallel.ForEach with async finishes before all the async tasks return