# Cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>'

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I believe I might just have the syntax wrong but what I'm trying to do is create a task that runs after another task is finished.

I have a task for each array of 100 in a list. It starts a new thread passing that array into a method. The method returns a dictionary when it finishes. I'm trying to create a task to run after the method is finishes where it passes the returned dictionary to a separate method that does some more work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                startDownload();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

public static async void startDownload()
    {
        try
        {

            DateTime currentDay = DateTime.Now;

            if (Helper.holidays.Contains(currentDay) == false)
            {
                List<string> markets = new List<string>() { "amex", "global", "nasdaq", "nyse" };

                Parallel.ForEach(markets, async market =>
                {
                    try
                    {

                        IEnumerable<string> symbolList = Helper.getStockSymbols(market);
                        var historicalGroups = symbolList.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                          .GroupBy(x => x.i / 100)
                          .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.x).ToArray());

                        Task<Dictionary<string, string>>[] historicalTasks =
                                                           historicalGroups.Select(x => Task.Run(() =>
                                                           Downloads.getHistoricalStockData(x, market)))
                                                                    .ToArray();

                        Dictionary<string, string>[] historcalStockResults = await
                                                                             Task.WhenAll(historicalTasks);

                        foreach (var dictionary in historcalStockResults)
                        {
                            Downloads.updateSymbolsInDB(dictionary);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                });

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you after an array of `Task<Dictionary<string, string>>` or an array of `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Also, what does `Downloads.updateSymbolsInDB` return?

Comment: public static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> getHistoricalStockData(string[] symbols, string market) I need to pass in the Task<Dictionary<string, string>>

Comment: @MikeGuthrie The updateSymbols method looks like this and returns void

public static void updateSymbolsInDB(Dictionary<string, string> errors)

Comment: Will `updateSymbolsInDB` run for each result of `getHistoricalStockData`, or is it supposed to run only once on the aggregate of all `getHistoricalStockData` results?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie    I was trying to have it run only once because I thought that would be more efficient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise not to use `ContinueWith` at all if you're already using `await`. The reason is the verbosity you end up with in your code.

Instead, use `await` where possible.
The code ends up like this:

```
var historicalGroups = symbolList
                       .Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                       .GroupBy(x => x.i / 100)
                       .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.x).ToArray());

var historicalTasks = historicalGroups.Select(x => Task.Run(() => 
                                       Downloads.getHistoricalStockData(x, market)))
                                      .ToArray();

var historcalStockResults = await Task.WhenAll(historicalTasks);

foreach (var dictionary in historcalStockResults)
{
    Downloads.updateSymbolsInDB(dictionary);
}
```

Note the use of `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. You should use that instead. More on that [*here*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

**Edit:**

If you need to execute this code once every 24 hours, add a `Task.Delay` and `await` on it :

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

**Edit 2:**

The reason your code isn't working is because `startDownload` is `async void`, and you're not awaiting on it. Thus your `while` loop keeps iterating regardless of your `Task.Delay`.

Because you're inside a Console Application, you can't `await` because `Main` methods cant be async. So to work around that, change `startDownload` to be `async Task` instead of `async void`, and `Wait` on that returned `Task`. Do note that using `Wait` should *almost* never be used, expect for special scenarios (such as the one while running inside a console app):

```
public async Task StartDownload()
```

and then

```
while (true)
{
    StartDownload().Wait();
}
```

Also note that mixing `Parallel.Foreach` and `async-await` isn't always the best idea. You can read more on that in [Nesting await in Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach)

Comment: @user3610374 I had answered before I fully understood what you were after, thus how I answered. *This* however is the answer I'd recommend, as it ends up with much more readable code.  If you still only wanted the single `Downloads.updateSymbolsInDB` call, you could replace the `foreach` block with the `Aggregate` logic as I had included in my answer.  But again, profile first to see if that is even beneficial.

Comment: I forgot to mention/ask one important thing. I have this code running in a loop and it is supposed to run again after 24 hours but I'm using Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(24)).Wait(); and this doesn't actually wait 24 hours. It keeps running the code over and over again. Is there a better way to run this with the one line method you mentioned?

Comment: Why are you using `Wait`? If you have this code running in some `while` loop, simply use `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));`

Comment: I tried that also but neither one is working. I inserted a breakline inside the while loop, and it keeps calling the method and running the code which isn't what I want. I believe await is a non blocking call so it just continues right?

Comment: Since all I'm doing is downloading data and saving it to a database as quickly as possible, should I just stick with TPL or use TPL Dataflow or just stick with async and await with the tasks?

Comment: It really depends on the job. If you're doing async IO, such as database calls, you can simply use `async-await`, no need for extra threading. If you're mixing async IO bound work with CPU bound work, i'd recommend using TPL dataflow.

Answer (score 2):

You'll see that [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321474.aspx) takes as Task as argument.

Also, from working through your logic in our comments, it looks like you'll need to update your code.  You are trying to run the `Downloads.updateSymbolsInDB` once on the result of all `WhenAll` tasks are completed.  In your case it looks like you'll need

```
await Task<Dictionary<string, string>>
    .WhenAll(historicalGroups.Select(g => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Downloads.getHistoricalStockData(g, market))))
    .ContinueWith((i) => Downloads.updateSymbolsInDB(i.Result.Aggregate((agg, next) =>
            {
                foreach (var p in next)
                {
                    if (!agg.ContainsKey(p.Key)) { agg.Add(p.Key, p.Value); }
                }
                return agg;
            })));
```

Note that I also used the `Task<TResult>` to initiate, so that the `ContinueWith` is strongly typed to provide the `Dictionary<string, string>` `i.Result`.

Also note that you'll want to revisit what I'm doing in the `i.Result.Aggregate` logic.  You'll need to update that to be correct to your case.  Additionally, it may be worth revisiting to see if it is more efficient to just call `Downloads.updateSymbolsInDB` multiple times, or if the `Aggregate` call is the better choice.

(Last note: the end result is a `void`, so the await isn't assigned.)

In review, there were a number of problems with your code (meant as a statement, not an accusation - no offense intended).  Your tasks created via `Task.Factory.StartNew` for your `WhenAll` method had no return value, thus were just basic `Task` objects, and were in fact throwing away the results of the `Downloads.getHistoricalStockData` work.  Then, your `ContinueWith` needed to work with the `Task<TResult>` of the `WhenAll`, where `TResult` will be an array of the return value of each task within `WhenAll`.

**EDIT:** As was asked how the code could be updated if `Downloads.updateSymbolsInDB` were to be called multiple times, it could simply be done as:

```
IEnumerable<string> symbolList = Helper.getStockSymbols(market);
var historicalGroups = symbolList.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.i / 100)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.x).ToArray());
Parallel.ForEach(historicalGroups, g => Downloads.updateSymbolsInDB(Downloads.getHistoricalStockData(g, market)));
```

Comment: Yeah I thought so as well but it gives me the error that Task doesn't contain a definition for Result

Comment: I updated my code and I'm still getting the error that Task doesn't contain a definition for Result

Comment: What would the correct code look like if I wanted to call the method multiple times?