# `Using Parallel.ForEach to speed up processing of file but cant return in correct order

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

so im trying to use a `Parallel.ForEach` loop to speed up my processing of a file but I can't figure out how to make it build the output in an ordered fashion. This is the code I have so far:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
List<string> list_lines = new List<string>(lines);

Parallel.ForEach(list_lines, async line =>
{
    processedData += await processSingleLine(line);
});
```

As you can see it doesn't have any sort of ordered implementation since I have tried looking for something to fit my solution I haven't found anything that I've been able to get even near working.
So preferably I'd like have each line processed but build up the `processedData` variable in the same order that each line was sent out, however I do realize that this might just be out of my current skill level so any advice would be nice.

EDIT:
After trying reading the answers below I tried it with two methods:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> result = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
Parallel.For(0, list.Length, i =>
{
    // process your data and save to dict
    result[i] = processData(lines[i]);
});
```

and

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> result = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    result[i] = lines[i];
}
Array.Clear(lines,0, lines.Length);
Parallel.ForEach(result, line =>
{
    result[line.Key] = encrypt(line.Value, key);
});
```

Yet both only appear to be using about 1 core(4 core processor), 30% of total in Task manager, where as before I implemented the ordering it was using near on 80% on the CPU.

Comment: You could have a queue of tasks put in the queue in order. You run the tasks. On completion of all, pick up the results from the tasks in order.

Comment: Don't use `await` with the TPL specifically `Parallel.ForEach`.  The two technologies are incompatible with each other. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach

Comment: Ah that makes sense, noted and will fix that up

Comment: Are you really seeing a speed up in processing time? I would be very surprised if you are! I suspect you should be in the I/O bound realm, unless your processing algorithm is extremely inoptimal.

Comment: @Aron the processes as a whole is just 4 separate `foreach` loops that do don't do anything too intensive, so I think that's just O(n), but the file I've been testing it with is about 280 000 lines and with my code at the top of the page it finished in about 3 minutes, without that code I left it for 15 minutes and I still hadn't finished, also since at the moment I'm only accessing the file at the start and end of the process, which is probably bad to leave everything in memory, but ill change this later once I have it running fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `Parallel.For` instead of `Parallel.ForEach`. Then you will have indexes for your lines. I.e.:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

// use thread safe collection for catching the results in parallel
ConcurrentDictionary<int, Data> result = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Data>();

Parallel.For(0, list.Length, i =>
{
    // process your data and save to dict
    result[i] = processData(lines[i]);
});

// having data in dict you can easily retrieve initial order
Data[] orderedData = Data[lines.Length];
for(var i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
{
    orderedData[i] = result[i];
}
```

**EDIT:** And as it was said in comments under your question, you can't use async methods here. When you do, `Parallel.ForEach` will return you a bunch of tasks, not results. If you want to parallelize asynchronous code, you can use multiple `Task.Run`, like here:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

var tasks = lines.Select(
                 l => Task.Run<Data>(
                         async () => {
                              return await processAsync(l);
                         })).ToList();

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

**NOTE:** Should work, but didn't check it.

Comment: Im not familiar with `ConcurrentDictionary` but will read up on them on MSDN, but it looks like this could solve my problems either way, thank you.

Comment: Hey @Michał Kędrzyński I tried implementing your first solution which appears to be working fine apart from  it doesn't appear to be using more than one core, or just not efficiently (using an average of about 32% of total CPU on a quad core) although RAM usage is way down, for comparison it was using up around 70-80% with my old code

Comment: Maybe try using explicit `Partitioner` which allows you to specify how items are distributed between threads.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Parallel.ForEach.AsOrdered() does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the data structure *list_lines* and the method *processSingleLine* from your code, the following should preserve the order and have parallel execution:

```
var parallelQuery = from line in list_lines.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
                    select processSingleLine(line);

foreach (var processedLine in parallelQuery)
{
    Console.Write(processedLine);
}
```