# Parallel execution for IO bound operations

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I have read TPL and Task library documents cover to cover. But, I still couldn't comprehend the following case very clearly and right now I need to implement it.

I will simplify my situation. I have an `IEnumerable<Uri>` of length 1000. I have to make a request for them using `HttpClient`.

I have two questions.

1. There is **not much computation**, just waiting for Http request. In this case can I still use `Parallel.Foreach()` ?
2. In case of using `Task` instead, what is the best practice for creating huge number of them? Let's say I use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and add those tasks to a list and wait for all of them. Is there a feature (such as TPL partitioner) that controls number of maximum tasks and maximum `HttpClient` I can create?

There are couple of similar questions on SO, but no one mentions the **maximums**. The requirement is just using maximum tasks with maximum HttpClient.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [Nesting await in Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### .NET 6

Starting from .NET 6 you can use one of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` methods which are `async` aware:

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    uris, 
    async (uri, cancellationToken) => await SendRequestAsync(uri, cancellationToken));
```

This will use `Environment.ProcessorCount` as the degree of parallelism. To change it you can use the overload that accepts `ParallelOptions`:

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    uris, 
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 },
    async (uri, cancellationToken) => await SendRequestAsync(uri, cancellationToken));
```

`ParallelOptions` also allows passing in a `CancellationToken` and a `TaskScheduler`

---

### .NET 5 and older (including all .NET Framework versions)

> In this case can I still use `Parallel.Foreach` ?

This isn't really appropriate. `Parallel.Foreach` is more for CPU intensive work. It also doesn't support async operations.

> In case of using `Task` instead, what is the best practice for creating huge number of them?

Use a TPL Dataflow block instead. You don't create huge amounts of tasks that sit there waiting for a thread to become available. You can configure the max amount of tasks and reuse them for all the items that meanwhile sit in a buffer waiting for a task. For example:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Uri>(
    uri => SendRequestAsync(uri),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 });

foreach (var uri in uris)
{
    block.Post(uri);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

Comment: What if number of concurrent requests exceeds the maximum number of http request operating system can make?

Comment: @ozgur That depends on where that limit is configured. But if there is one then make sure to set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to something lower than that.

Comment: Last Question. The example you provided is suitable for IO operations but it doesn't require cpu parallelism?

Comment: @ozgur it's suitable for both. The only difference would be in the degree of parallelism. For CPU work you shouldn't have more tasks than available cores. For I/O however, you definitely should.

Comment: Your last comment confused me a little. So, this is different than Parallel.Foreach in terms of what?

Comment: @ozgur `Parallel.Foreach` is "old". It's from .Net 4.0. It's only appropriate for CPU bound work. TPL dataflow is new. It's from .Net 4.5. It's appropriate for both CPU and I/O bound work. And it supports async operations.

Comment: Is parallel foreach meant for io or cpu bound tasks?

Comment: @variable CPU. But the new `Parallel.ForEachAsync` works for IO bound..

Answer (score 49):

i3arnon's answer with TPL Dataflow is good; Dataflow is useful especially if you have a mix of CPU and I/O bound code. I'll echo his sentiment that `Parallel` is designed for CPU-bound code; it's not the best solution for I/O-based code, and *especially* not appropriate for asynchronous code.

If you want an alternative solution that works well with mostly-I/O code - and doesn't require an external library - the method you're looking for is `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var tasks = uris.Select(uri => SendRequestAsync(uri)).ToArray();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This is the easiest solution, but it does have the drawback of starting all requests simultaneously. Particularly if all requests are going to the same service (or a small set of services), this can cause timeouts. To solve this, you need to use some kind of throttling...

> Is there a feature (such as TPL partitioner) that controls number of maximum tasks and maximum HttpClient I can create?

TPL Dataflow has that nice `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` which only starts so many at a time. You can also throttle regular asynchronous code by using another builtin, `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(50);
private async Task SendRequestAsync(Uri uri)
{
  await _sem.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    ...
  }
  finally
  {
    _sem.Release();
  }
}
```

> In case of using Task instead, what is the best practice for creating huge number of them? Let's say I use Task.Factory.StartNew() and add those tasks to a list and wait for all of them.

You actually don't want to use `StartNew`. It only has one appropriate use case (dynamic task-based parallelism), which is extremely rare. Modern code should use `Task.Run` if you need to push work onto a background thread. But you don't even need that to begin with, so neither `StartNew` nor `Task.Run` is appropriate here.

> There are couple of similar questions on SO, but no one mentions the maximums. The requirement is just using maximum tasks with maximum HttpClient.

Maximums are where asynchronous code really gets tricky. With CPU-bound (parallel) code, the solution is obvious: you use as many threads as you have cores. (Well, at least you can *start* there and adjust as necessary). With asynchronous code, there isn't as obvious of a solution. It depends on a lot of factors - how much memory you have, how the remote server responds (rate limiting, timeouts, etc), etc.

There's no easy solutions here. You just have to test out how your specific application deals with high levels of concurrency, and then throttle to some lower number.

---

I have some [slides for a talk](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Presentations/tree/a406324f894da3ca50676e7b3f5bd40dc3078061/Asynchronous%20Parallel%20Reactive%20-%20HELP!) that attempts to explain when different technologies are appropriate (parallelism, asynchrony, TPL Dataflow, and Rx). If you prefer more of a written description with recipes, I think you may benefit from [my book](http://stephencleary.com/book/) on concurrency.

Comment: When you said there is no easy solution it ended my pain. I was thinking that there is probably a way to do that and and was searching day and night. Now I can try to implement something specific for my own situation. Thank you very much.