# How do I iterate over two lists using Foreach.Parallel

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, parallel-processing

I am facing quite a struggle, I want to iterate over a list using `Parallel.Foreach`.

So picture this

```
static List<string> proxyList = new List<string>();
static List<string> websiteList = new List<string>();
```

Each list is looking something like this

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
```

And the website list

```
https://google.com
https://spotify.com
https://duckduckgo.com
https://amazon.com
```

I want to achieve something like this but I have no idea how, no matter how I twist and turn I cant seem to find any logic.

```
Foreach(var proxy in proxyList)
{
    If(proxyIsAlive)
        //Try to connect to the first website in the website list
    else
       //Try the next proxy until I get a working one 
       //and then try to connect to the most recent one
    }
 }
```

The issue I am facing is that I have to idea how to access the websites in the website list, I want to connect to

**EDIT**: this is what my logic looks like so far

```
private static void Connect()
{
   string tproxy = "";
   int port;

   foreach (var website in websiteList)
   {
      foreach (var proxy in proxyList)
      {
         var proxySplit = proxy.Split(':');
         tproxy = proxySplit[0];
         port = Convert.ToInt32(proxySplit[1]);
         //if(ProxyIsAlive)

      }
      //Use that proxy down here to connect
   }
}
```

I only want to move out of the proxy foreach IF ProxyIsAlive returns true

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: @Saruman It's not that its not working its that I cant find the logic to how to structure the thing I want to structure

Comment: What do you want to do? check if a proxy works and do some other actions all in parallel if it does?

Comment: Imagine this, I have a list of proxies, I want to check 4 at a time if they are working, hence the parallel with the option of 4, and then if it finds one that works, I want to connect to a website using that working one, so let's say 2 out of those 4 worked, I want to connect to two websites using those proxies, the websites are all different and they are stored in a list. Am I making any sense?

Comment: The first unused website in the list? (ie block access to that website until it is finished) or access them sequentially until they have all been used once

Comment: I want to access each website in the website list with a unique proxy from the proxy list, in my head it should get the proxies with a foreach because that seems to be logical,

Comment: So in essence, you want to go to each website and use a working proxy and if so check the most recent working proxy first?\

Comment: I'll add a code snippet in the question give me 20 seconds

Comment: Do you want to check to see if the proxy is alive each time, is that IO call i.e call to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes :

- This uses nested Parallel as per your original question
- It assumes you want to check the last good proxy first
- If a good proxy is found it updates the success time
- It processes each website and proxy in parallel

> **Note** : Parallel.ForEach is suited for CPU-bound tasks, you need to be
>   careful you aren't just wasting resources blocking threads waiting for
>   IO operations to complete

Class to hold proxy info

```
public class Proxy
{
   public string Host { get; set; }
   public int Port { get; set; }
   public DateTime LastSuccess { get; set; }

   public Proxy(string value)
   {
      var proxySplit = value.Split(':');
      Host = proxySplit[0];
      Port = Convert.ToInt32(proxySplit[1]);
      LastSuccess = DateTime.MinValue;
   }
}
```

Code to run in parallel

```
var proxies = proxyList.Select(x => new Proxy(x)).ToList();

Parallel.ForEach(webSites, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, site =>
   {
      Parallel.ForEach(proxies.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastSuccess), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, proxy =>
      {               
         if(!CheckProxy(proxy))
         {
            //check next proxy
            return;
         }
         // if we found a good proxy
         // update the lastSuccess so we check that first
         proxy.LastSuccess = DateTime.Now;
         // do something to the website 
      });
   });
}
```

> **Note** : This may not be the best approach, if you have CPU-bound code,
>   parallelism is appropriate; if you have I/O-bound code, asynchrony is
>   appropriate. In this case, an HttpClientExtension.GetHttpResponse is
>   clearly I/O, so the ideal consuming code would be asynchronous.

I would consider looking up the topics **Parallel execution for IO bound operations**

Existing SO questions deal with this Such as

[Parallel execution for IO bound operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686341/parallel-execution-for-io-bound-operations)

[Parallel.ForEach vs Async Forloop in Heavy I/O Ops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075845/parallel-foreach-vs-async-forloop-in-heavy-i-o-ops)

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up doing.

```
private static void ConnectToWebsite()
        {
            var proxyIP = "";
            int port;

            foreach (var website in WebsiteList)
            {
                foreach (var proxy in proxyList)
                {
                    var proxySplit = proxy.Split(':');
                    proxyIP = proxySplit[0];
                    var convert = Int32.TryParse(proxySplit[1], out port);
                    if(HttpClientExtension.GetHttpResponse(getCMYIP, proxyIP, port))
                        Console.WriteLine(website + proxy);
                }
            }
        }
```

That will check proxies until it finds a working one.
Now I need to make this async to speed things up.