# Asynchronously invoking a parallel for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I would like to do something like this:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    // Do some preparation

    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(0, count, i => { // Do some work //});

    // do some finalization
}
```

However, I did not find an elegant way of doing so. I thought of two ways, but they are sub-optimal:

1. The only thing I thought about is manually partitioning the range, creating tasks, and then using Task.WhenAll.
2. Using the following code `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.For(...));`.
   The problem is that it "wastes" a thread on the asynchronous task.
3. Using TPL Dataflow's ActionBlock, and posting the integers one by one. The drawback is that it does not partition the range in a smart way like Parallel.For does, and works on each iteration one by one.
4. Manually using a Partitioner with Partitioner.Create, but it is less elegant. I want the framework to do intelligent partitioning for me.

Comment: Is your forEach operation IO or cpu bound?

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallell-foreach (used as duplicate) provides all sensible ways to mix `async` and `Parallel.ForEach`. If that's does not answer your particular case - make sure to [edit] your post explaining why so it can be re-opened.

Comment: Edited. Please re-consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a regular synchronous parallel loop that you'd like to invoke asynchronously (presumably to move it off the UI thread).

You can do this the same way you'd move any other CPU-bound work off the UI thread: using `Task.Run`:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
  // Do some preparation

  await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(0, count, i => { /* Do some work */ }));

  // do some finalization
}
```

There is no thread "wasted" because `Parallel.ForEach` will use the calling thread as one of its worker threads.

(This is recipe 7.4 "Async Wrappers for Parallel Code" in [my book](http://stephencleary.com/book/)).