# Understanding TPL Dataflow, Blocks, and Continuation Tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am working on a project where a need arose that is a perfect scenario for TPL Dataflow. Having relatively limited experience with it (and what I do have was done some time ago), I have been brushing up on it by reading Microsoft's documentation as well as articles I can find online.

Having done that, I built my code to chain together a series of blocks (mostly `TransformBlock` and ending with an `ActionBlock` doing something like this:

```
var block1 = new TransformBlock<T, U>(async input => {});
var block2 = new TransformBlock<U, V>(async input => {});
var block3 = new ActionBlock<V>(async input => {});

block1.LinkTo(block2);
block2.LinkTo(block3);

foreach(var item in items)
{
   await block1.SendAsync(item);
}
block1.Complete();
await block3.Completion;
```

Someone in an article (which I can't find) suggested that there should be continuation tasks in the pipeline to mark blocks as complete. This is the code they provided for that.

```
// Create the continuation tasks in the pipeline that marks each block as complete.
await block1.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted) { ((IDataflowBlock)block2).Fault(t.Exception); }
    else { block2.Complete(); }
});
await block2.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted) { ((IDataflowBlock)block3).Fault(t.Exception); }
    else { block3.Complete(); }
});
```

I will admit that I don't fully understand what this code is doing and whether it is even needed. When I attempt to run this in the code I just wrote, the code hangs on the first `ContinueWith` and it never makes it to running the pipeline.

I would appreciate additional explanation since I want to get a better understanding of the nuances of what is going on here.

Comment: You should not be asking multiple separate questions per question.  Additionally, explaining the entirety of some concept is Too Broad.  You should be asking a *single, specific* question.

Comment: @Servy I removed my first question. How would you suggest asking the second part? I provided a piece of code that I do not understand why someone said it was important (and the article didn't explain it either). At this point, I haven't found/read anything that helped me to understand it better.

Comment: You didn't find *anything* about how completion of blocks works, and you need people to explain you *all* of the nuances of how competition works?  For the first part, there's plenty of info about how completion of blocks works, for the second, again, that's Too Broad.

Comment: I didn't say I didn't find anything at all...I said I didn't understand that piece of code from the article. I provided specific code. @JSteward provided a good answer, I believe and his link provides more detail to the specific code above so that helps. Perhaps my Google-fu is completely failing. I will work to craft a clearer question in the future, but someone was able to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do for a linear pipeline is to `PropagateCompletion`. That option propagates `Completion` as well as `Faults` whose exception is then attached to the final `Completion Task`:

```
var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true };
block1.LinkTo(block2, linkOptions);
block2.LinkTo(block3, linkOptions);
```

The continuations are unnecessary. But if you have pipeline that distributes to multiple blocks you'll need to handle completion and fault propagation yourself [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310402/tpl-complete-vs-completion/47311537#47311537).

> the code hangs on the first `ContinueWith`

That happens because you `await` the continuation, so if you do that before calling `Complete()` then `block1` will never complete.