# TPL Dataflow Pipeline completion not returning from wait

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a pipeline that is not getting registering as complete even though all the data has been processed and displayed on the console. I have it set to wait on the completion, but it never finishes and isn't allowing the method to return.

```
    TransformBlock<string, CompanyInfo> GetCompanyInfo;
    TransformBlock<string, List<Dividend>> GetDividendReports;
    TransformBlock<string, KeyStats> GetKeyStatInfo;
    TransformBlock<string, List<Interval>> GetIntervalReports;
    TransformBlock<List<Interval>, List<decimal>> GetChangesOverInterval;
    BroadcastBlock<string> broadcastSymbol;
    TransformBlock<Tuple<List<decimal>, List<Dividend>, KeyStats>, string> GenerateXmlString;
    ActionBlock<string> GenerateCompleteReport;
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;


    public Task StartPipeline()
    {
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            CancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MAXPARA
        };

        broadcastSymbol = new BroadcastBlock<string>(symbol => symbol);
        var joinblock = new JoinBlock<List<decimal>, List<Dividend>, KeyStats>(new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { Greedy = false });

        GetCompanyInfo = new TransformBlock<string, CompanyInfo>(symbol =>
        {
            return RetrieveCompanyInfo(symbol);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GetDividendReports = new TransformBlock<string, List<Dividend>>(symbol =>
        {
            return RetrieveDividendInfo(symbol);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GetKeyStatInfo = new TransformBlock<string, KeyStats>(symbol =>
        {
            return RetrieveKeyStats(symbol);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GetIntervalReports = new TransformBlock<string, List<Interval>>(symbol =>
        {
            return RetrieveIntervals(symbol, 30);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GetChangesOverInterval = new TransformBlock<List<Interval>, List<decimal>>(intervals =>
        {
            return ConstructIntervalReport(intervals);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GenerateXmlString = new TransformBlock<Tuple<List<decimal>, List<Dividend>, KeyStats>, string>(tup =>
        {
            var ReportObj = new Report
            {
                changeIntervals = tup.Item1,
                dividends = tup.Item2,
                keyStats = tup.Item3
            };

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            ser.Serialize(stringWriter, ReportObj);
            return stringWriter.ToString();

        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GenerateCompleteReport = new ActionBlock<string>(xml =>
        {
            var str = Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", "") + ".xml";
            File.WriteAllText(str, xml);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished File");
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        var options = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };

        var buffer = new BufferBlock<string>();
        buffer.LinkTo(broadcastSymbol);

        //Broadcasts the symbol
        broadcastSymbol.LinkTo(GetIntervalReports, options);
        broadcastSymbol.LinkTo(GetDividendReports, options);
        broadcastSymbol.LinkTo(GetKeyStatInfo, options);
        //Second teir parallel 
        GetIntervalReports.LinkTo(GetChangesOverInterval, options);
        //Joins the parallel blocks back together
        GetDividendReports.LinkTo(joinblock.Target2, options);
        GetKeyStatInfo.LinkTo(joinblock.Target3, options);
        GetChangesOverInterval.LinkTo(joinblock.Target1, options);

        joinblock.LinkTo(GenerateXmlString, options);
        GenerateXmlString.LinkTo(GenerateCompleteReport, options);

        buffer.Post("F");
        buffer.Post("AGFS");
        buffer.Post("BAC");
        buffer.Post("FCF");

        buffer.Complete();

        GenerateCompleteReport.Completion.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    }
```

I'm not sure why it isn't returning from the pipeline with an exception or completion. When the program runs it shows all the files being created and stops, but no code executes after the wait completion. Shouldn't the PropagateCompletion  allow for the blocks to know when they have completed their actions or transforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not passing the link options to your `BufferBlock` so completion is not being propagated. On another note only one linked block will receive completion from your `BroadcastBlock`. If you want wait for all three linked blocks you'll have to handle that explicitly on your own. [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47311537/7339946)

Additionally since the method already returns a `Task` its unnecessary to return a `Task.CompletedTask`, you could simply use `async/sawait` instead of blocking with `.Wait()`. And what would you expect a caller that `await`s this method to do with `null`?

```
if (GenerateCompleteReport.Completion.IsCompletedSuccessfully) { return Task.CompletedTask;  }

        return null;
```

Instead you could:

```
await enerateCompleteReport.Completion
```

Comment: Yeah not sure what I was doing with the returning null, thanks for the answer I figured I was forgetting something with the propagation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being not linking the propagation to the buffer block, which wasn't allowing any blocks to receive completion events. Also, I needed to have all the receiving blocks from the broadcast receive the complete status as I wasn't aware that broadcast blocks only send a complete event to one of the linked blocks.

After adding these changes the pipeline works as I expected it to.

```
    readonly string _baseUrl = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/";
    const int MAXPARA = 2;

    TransformBlock<string, CompanyInfo> GetCompanyInfo;
    TransformBlock<string, List<Dividend>> GetDividendReports;
    TransformBlock<string, KeyStats> GetKeyStatInfo;
    TransformBlock<string, List<Interval>> GetIntervalReports;
    TransformBlock<List<Interval>, List<decimal>> GetChangesOverInterval;
    BroadcastBlock<string> broadcastSymbol;
    TransformBlock<Tuple<List<decimal>, List<Dividend>, KeyStats>, string> GenerateXmlString;
    ActionBlock<string> GenerateCompleteReport;
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    public void StartPipeline()
    {

        //Add cancelation to the pipeline
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            CancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MAXPARA
        };

        broadcastSymbol = new BroadcastBlock<string>(symbol => symbol);
        var joinblock = new JoinBlock<List<decimal>, List<Dividend>, KeyStats>(new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { Greedy = false });

        GetCompanyInfo = new TransformBlock<string, CompanyInfo>(symbol =>
        {
            return RetrieveCompanyInfo(symbol);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GetDividendReports = new TransformBlock<string, List<Dividend>>(symbol =>
        {
            return RetrieveDividendInfo(symbol);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GetKeyStatInfo = new TransformBlock<string, KeyStats>(symbol =>
        {
            return RetrieveKeyStats(symbol);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GetIntervalReports = new TransformBlock<string, List<Interval>>(symbol =>
        {
            return RetrieveIntervals(symbol, 30);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GetChangesOverInterval = new TransformBlock<List<Interval>, List<decimal>>(intervals =>
        {
            return ConstructIntervalReport(intervals);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GenerateXmlString = new TransformBlock<Tuple<List<decimal>, List<Dividend>, KeyStats>, string>(tup =>
        {
            var ReportObj = new Report
            {
                changeIntervals = tup.Item1,
                dividends = tup.Item2,
                keyStats = tup.Item3
            };

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            ser.Serialize(stringWriter, ReportObj);
            return stringWriter.ToString();

        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        GenerateCompleteReport = new ActionBlock<string>(xml =>
        {
            var str = Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", "") + ".xml";
            File.WriteAllText(str, xml);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished File");
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        var options = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };

        var buffer = new BufferBlock<string>();
        buffer.LinkTo(broadcastSymbol, options);

        //Need to make sure all data is recieved for each linked block
        //Broadcast block only sends completion notice to one of the linked blocks
        broadcastSymbol.Completion.ContinueWith(tsk =>
        {
            if(!tsk.IsFaulted)
            {
                GetIntervalReports.Complete();
                GetDividendReports.Complete();
                GetKeyStatInfo.Complete();
            }
            else
            {
                ((IDataflowBlock)GetIntervalReports).Fault(tsk.Exception);
                ((IDataflowBlock)GetDividendReports).Fault(tsk.Exception);
                ((IDataflowBlock)GetKeyStatInfo).Fault(tsk.Exception);
            }
        });


        //Broadcasts the symbol
        broadcastSymbol.LinkTo(GetIntervalReports, options);
        broadcastSymbol.LinkTo(GetDividendReports, options);
        broadcastSymbol.LinkTo(GetKeyStatInfo, options);
        //Second teir parallel 
        GetIntervalReports.LinkTo(GetChangesOverInterval, options);
        //Joins the parallel blocks back together
        GetDividendReports.LinkTo(joinblock.Target2, options);
        GetKeyStatInfo.LinkTo(joinblock.Target3, options);
        GetChangesOverInterval.LinkTo(joinblock.Target1, options);

        joinblock.LinkTo(GenerateXmlString, options);
        GenerateXmlString.LinkTo(GenerateCompleteReport, options);

        buffer.Post("F");
        buffer.Post("AGFS");
        buffer.Post("BAC");
        buffer.Post("FCF");


        buffer.Complete();

        GenerateCompleteReport.Completion.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    }
```