# How to complete a Block after JoinBlock

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I have below senario to perform the data flow with TPL. `a` and `b` are some datasource joined together, then pass through the data flow.

```
var a = new TransformBlock<object, int>(_ => 1);
var b = new TransformBlock<object, int>(_ => 2);

var join = new JoinBlock<int, int>(new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { Greedy = false });

var transform = new TransformBlock<Tuple<int, int>, int>(uri =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Handling '{0}'...", uri);
    return uri.Item1;
});

var printReversedWords = new ActionBlock<int>(ddd => Console.WriteLine(ddd));

var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };

a.LinkTo(join.Target1);
b.LinkTo(join.Target2);
join.LinkTo(transform);
transform.LinkTo(printReversedWords, linkOptions);

a.Post(1);
b.Post(1);
Task.WhenAll(a.Completion, b.Completion).ContinueWith(_ => join.Complete());
printReversedWords.Completion.Wait();
```

After all of this, I can see the log in the console like:

> Handling '<1, 2>'...
>
> 1

That means the ActionBlock `printReversedWords` has been processed. However, it is still waiting at the last line, never ends.

Could anyone tell me what should I update on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the pipeline you need to call `Complete` on the first block in the chain. In your case you'll need to make sure `Complete()` is called on both blocks `a` and `b`. And you'll need to propagate completion from the `JoinBlock`

Also, instead of a blocking call to `.Wait()` it's usually better to make the method `async` and `await` completion.

When you configure the the continuation make sure to handle exceptions as well as sucessfull completion by faulting the downstream blocks, [An example is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47311537/7339946).

```
//Propagate Completion    
join.LinkTo(transform, linkOptions); 
transform.LinkTo(printReversedWords, linkOptions);

a.Post(1);
b.Post(1);

//Complete the start of the pipeline
a.Complete();
b.Complete();

await Task.WhenAll(a.Completion, b.Completion).ContinueWith(_ => join.Complete());
await printReversedWords.Completion;
```

Comment: Hi JSteward, I updated the code to add 'a.Complete(); b.Complete()'. But it still doesn't complete in the end. Actually I found another way to resolve this by adding a BroadcastBlock on the top (say 'startBlock'), then call 'startBlock.Complete()', and it works.

Comment: Glad you got it working! FYI - In the posted code, you would have had to propagate completion from the `JoinBlock` to the `TransformBlock` to flow completion all the way.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Propagate the completion through each block leads to the end. Thanks!