# How to write to an object after TransformBlock?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, tpl-dataflow

I have a list of objects that I need to iterate over parallely. This is what I need to do:

```
foreach (var r in results)
{
    r.SomeList = await apiHelper.Get(r.Id);
}
```

Since I want to parellelize it, I tried to use Parallel.ForEach() but it doesn't wait until everything is really complete since
apiHelper.Get() is doing an await inside of its own.

```
Parallel.ForEach(
                results,
                async (r) =>
                {
                    r.SomeList = await apiHelper.Get(r.Id);
                });
```

So I searched online and found this:
[Nesting await in Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Now I am very new to TPL (20 mins old) and I may be missing something obvious. How do I go ahead?

```
        var getBlock = new TransformBlock<string, List<Something>>(
            async i =>
            {
                var c = await apiHelper.Get(i);
                return c;
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded
            });

        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            r.SomeList = getBlock.Post(r.Id);  // ERROR: Can't convert boolean to list.
        }

        getBlock.Complete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an a example using [ActionBlock Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) in the [TPL dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library.

It basically give you parallel, and `async` and its fairly easy to understand

**Dataflow example**

```
public static async Task DoWorkLoads(List<Something> results)
{
   var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                     {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
                     };

   var block = new ActionBlock<Something>(MyMethodAsync, options);

   foreach (var result in results)
      block.Post(result );

   block.Complete();
   await block.Completion;

}

...

public async Task MyMethodAsync(Something result)
{       
   result.SomeList = await apiHelper.Get(result.Id);
}
```

Obviously, you will need error checking, and add pepper and salt to taste

Also, its assuming `apiHelper` is thread safe

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps consider using Microsoft's Reactive Framework instead.

Here's the code:

```
var query =
    from r in results.ToObservable()
    from l in Observable.FromAsync(() => apiHelper.Get(r.Id))
    select new { r, l };

query
    .Subscribe(x => x.r.SomeList = x.l);
```

Done. Parallel and async.

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" and add a `using System.Reactiive.Linq;`.

Comment: I  have been meaning to learn me some reactive, every time i go to the site the page puts me off though, +1 for learning me something

Answer (score 0):

To call an api asyncrounously and in parallel you don't need Reactive or Dataflow. The only complication with what you have is that you're mutating the object `r` by setting it's property with the result of the api call. Still though, what you want is pretty simple:

This:

```
foreach (var r in results)
{
    r.SomeList = await apiHelper.Get(r.Id);
}
```

Becomes:

```
var tasks = results.Select(async r => { r.SomeList = await apiHelper.Get(r.Id); });
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Assuming `apiHelper.Get` is in fact non-blocking and async then each item within `results` will have an asynchronous and parallel call to the api.