# Why is my mongo .net driver code not concurrency safe?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, mongodb-.net-driver

WiredTiger is supposed to handle document level concurrency. 
Is the Mongo .Net Driver compatible with this locking mechanism ?

Why is this code not giving me the right result :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 1;

    public List<int> Prop { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassRepository : Repository<int, MyClass>
{    
    public async Task TestUpdate(MyClass document, int val)
    {
        var filter = Builders<MyClass>.Filter.Eq("_id", document.Id);
        var update = Builders<MyClass>.Update.Push(_ => _.Prop, val);
        await this.Collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
    }
}

[Fact]
public async Task Test2()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass { Prop = new List<int>() };

    Parallel.For(
        0,
        100,
        async i =>
        {
            await this._repository.TestUpdate(myClass, i);
        });

    var result = await this._repository.Get(1);
    result.Prop.Count.Should().Be(100);
}
```

I don't always see 100 ints in my document in mongo database...

Something interesting is, when I check the mongo stack, i see only 93 update calls to mongo and 93 ints in my mongo collection. Therefore, I'm concluding that the driver is the issue.

Mongo stack :

```js
   
{ 
"op" : "update", 
"ns" : "auditing.myclasses", 
"command" : {
    "q" : {
        "_id" : NumberInt(1)
    }, 
    "u" : {
        "$push" : {
            "Prop" : NumberInt(42)
        }
    }, 
    "multi" : false, 
    "upsert" : false
}, 
"keysExamined" : NumberInt(1), 
"docsExamined" : NumberInt(1), 
"nMatched" : NumberInt(1), 
"nModified" : NumberInt(1), 
"numYield" : NumberInt(0), 
"locks" : {
    "Global" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(1), 
            "w" : NumberLong(1)
        }
    }, 
    "Database" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "w" : NumberLong(1)
        }
    }, 
    "Collection" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "w" : NumberLong(1)
        }
    }
}, 
"millis" : NumberInt(0), 
"planSummary" : "IDHACK", 
"execStats" : {
    "stage" : "UPDATE", 
    "nReturned" : NumberInt(0), 
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
    "works" : NumberInt(2), 
    "advanced" : NumberInt(0), 
    "needTime" : NumberInt(1), 
    "needYield" : NumberInt(0), 
    "saveState" : NumberInt(0), 
    "restoreState" : NumberInt(0), 
    "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
    "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
    "nMatched" : NumberInt(1), 
    "nWouldModify" : NumberInt(1), 
    "nInvalidateSkips" : NumberInt(0), 
    "wouldInsert" : false, 
    "fastmodinsert" : false, 
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IDHACK", 
        "nReturned" : NumberInt(1), 
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
        "works" : NumberInt(1), 
        "advanced" : NumberInt(1), 
        "needTime" : NumberInt(0), 
        "needYield" : NumberInt(0), 
        "saveState" : NumberInt(1), 
        "restoreState" : NumberInt(1), 
        "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
        "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
        "keysExamined" : NumberInt(1), 
        "docsExamined" : NumberInt(1)
    }
}, 
"ts" : ISODate("2019-04-12T11:46:59.118+0000"), 
"client" : "127.0.0.1", 
"appName" : "Auditing", 
"allUsers" : [

], 
"user" : ""
}
```

Comment: The queries that come from this, what do they look like?

Comment: (it's been a while since I touched C# and I'm a little confused by what's happening in the update section. This is the [Update.Push](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Update_Push.htm), I'm assuming? But it accepts a string and not a lambda. It's also very possible that I'm misreading the syntax here)

Comment: see snippet above

Comment: Created an issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2584. Let's see what is the outcome about this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got to the bottom of this. Issue is purely c# related and came from using async/await syntax inside the Parallel.For block.

Replacing the code with the one below fixed the issue.

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test2()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass { Prop = new List<int>() };

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(this._repository.TestUpdate(myClass, i));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    var result = await this._repository.Get(1);
    result.Prop.Count.Should().Be(100);
}
```

What brought me to this conclusion is that commenting the Get and assert part resulted in no data being inserted in Mongo at all.

For more info about this see
[Nesting await in Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach)

Thanks to those who investigated this and sorry for the inconvenience.