# How to process Parallel.ForEach results when available as fast as possible?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, benchmarking

I am trying to optimize the process of a big collection (~ 1million items or so). I am thinking about using `Parallel.ForEach` but it seems that it does not make things necessarily faster in my case.

Basically the process is two-folds:

1. Process the collection with some CPU bound operations
2. Perform some IO bound (database-related stuff)

One optimization I was thinking of is to process the part of the collection that has been processed in 1. through a `BlockingCollection`.

The theory is that processing 1. with `Parallel.ForEach` is faster than using a sequential approach, but it would be better if the IO could be whenever a result of CPU bound operation is block (but this part has to been done sequentially... due to the related DB locks...) so that at least 1. is optimized and faster.

```
public static class Program
{
    [CoreJob]
    [RPlotExporter, RankColumn]
    public class Paralleling
    {
        private IEnumerable<int> _items;

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _items = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);
        }

        public static long Ackermann(long m, long n)
        {
            if (m > 0)
            {
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    return Ackermann(m - 1, Ackermann(m, n - 1));
                }

                if (n == 0)
                {
                    return Ackermann(m - 1, 1);
                }
            }
            else if (m == 0)
            {
                if (n >= 0)
                {
                    return n + 1;
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public async Task ParallelAndSequential()
        {
            var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<(bool, int, int)>();

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(_items, item =>
                {
                    Ackermann(0, 2);
                    var dummy = item % 2 == 0;
                    blockingCollection.Add((dummy, item, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                });
                blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
            });

            using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
            {
                foreach (var result in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(result.ToString());
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                }
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public async Task AllSequential()
        {
            using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
            {
                foreach (var item in _items)
                {
                    Ackermann(0, 2);
                    var dummy = item % 2 == 0;
                    var result = (dummy, item, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(result.ToString());
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Paralleling>();
    }
}
```

The results of the benchmark:

```
// Validating benchmarks:
// ***** BenchmarkRunner: Start   *****
// ***** Found 2 benchmark(s) in total *****
// ***** Building 1 exe(s) in Parallel: Start   *****
// start dotnet restore  /p:UseSharedCompilation=false /p:BuildInParallel=false /m:1 in C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\Playground\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\e6babe6d-16ff-42cd-aa3e-d457250f812c
// command took 1.83s and exited with 0
// start dotnet build -c Release  --no-restore /p:UseSharedCompilation=false /p:BuildInParallel=false /m:1 in C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\Playground\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\e6babe6d-16ff-42cd-aa3e-d457250f812
c
// command took 3.48s and exited with 0
// ***** Done, took 00:00:05 (5.46 sec)   *****
// Found 2 benchmarks:
//   Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential: Core(Runtime=Core)
//   Paralleling.AllSequential: Core(Runtime=Core)

Setup power plan (GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c FriendlyName: High performance)// **************************
// Benchmark: Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential: Core(Runtime=Core)
// *** Execute ***
// Launch: 1 / 1
// Execute: dotnet "e6babe6d-16ff-42cd-aa3e-d457250f812c.dll" --benchmarkName "ConsoleApp.Program+Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential" --job "Core" --benchmarkId 0 in C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\Playground\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\bin\Re
lease\netcoreapp2.2\e6babe6d-16ff-42cd-aa3e-d457250f812c\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2
// BeforeAnythingElse

// Benchmark Process Environment Information:
// Runtime=.NET Core 2.2.3 (CoreCLR 4.6.27414.05, CoreFX 4.6.27414.05), 64bit RyuJIT
// GC=Concurrent Workstation
// Job: Core(Runtime=Core)

OverheadJitting  1: 1 op, 595300.00 ns, 595.3000 us/op
WorkloadJitting  1: 1 op, 15646340800.00 ns, 15.6463 s/op

WorkloadWarmup   1: 1 op, 15623246700.00 ns, 15.6232 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   2: 1 op, 15633394200.00 ns, 15.6334 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   3: 1 op, 15621610400.00 ns, 15.6216 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   4: 1 op, 15623904400.00 ns, 15.6239 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   5: 1 op, 15628894600.00 ns, 15.6289 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   6: 1 op, 15619927500.00 ns, 15.6199 s/op

// BeforeActualRun
WorkloadActual   1: 1 op, 15622656400.00 ns, 15.6227 s/op
WorkloadActual   2: 1 op, 15625515000.00 ns, 15.6255 s/op
WorkloadActual   3: 1 op, 15615469600.00 ns, 15.6155 s/op
WorkloadActual   4: 1 op, 15631936300.00 ns, 15.6319 s/op
WorkloadActual   5: 1 op, 15619036800.00 ns, 15.6190 s/op
WorkloadActual   6: 1 op, 15622770800.00 ns, 15.6228 s/op
WorkloadActual   7: 1 op, 15625282100.00 ns, 15.6253 s/op
WorkloadActual   8: 1 op, 15621714600.00 ns, 15.6217 s/op
WorkloadActual   9: 1 op, 15641690200.00 ns, 15.6417 s/op
WorkloadActual  10: 1 op, 15661029200.00 ns, 15.6610 s/op
WorkloadActual  11: 1 op, 15625002000.00 ns, 15.6250 s/op
WorkloadActual  12: 1 op, 15614647200.00 ns, 15.6146 s/op
WorkloadActual  13: 1 op, 15630444900.00 ns, 15.6304 s/op
WorkloadActual  14: 1 op, 15620751600.00 ns, 15.6208 s/op
WorkloadActual  15: 1 op, 15639731400.00 ns, 15.6397 s/op

// AfterActualRun
WorkloadResult   1: 1 op, 15622656400.00 ns, 15.6227 s/op
WorkloadResult   2: 1 op, 15625515000.00 ns, 15.6255 s/op
WorkloadResult   3: 1 op, 15615469600.00 ns, 15.6155 s/op
WorkloadResult   4: 1 op, 15631936300.00 ns, 15.6319 s/op
WorkloadResult   5: 1 op, 15619036800.00 ns, 15.6190 s/op
WorkloadResult   6: 1 op, 15622770800.00 ns, 15.6228 s/op
WorkloadResult   7: 1 op, 15625282100.00 ns, 15.6253 s/op
WorkloadResult   8: 1 op, 15621714600.00 ns, 15.6217 s/op
WorkloadResult   9: 1 op, 15641690200.00 ns, 15.6417 s/op
WorkloadResult  10: 1 op, 15625002000.00 ns, 15.6250 s/op
WorkloadResult  11: 1 op, 15614647200.00 ns, 15.6146 s/op
WorkloadResult  12: 1 op, 15630444900.00 ns, 15.6304 s/op
WorkloadResult  13: 1 op, 15620751600.00 ns, 15.6208 s/op
WorkloadResult  14: 1 op, 15639731400.00 ns, 15.6397 s/op
GC:  0 0 0 0 0

// AfterAll

Mean = 15.6255 s, StdErr = 0.0022 s (0.01%); N = 14, StdDev = 0.0081 s
Min = 15.6146 s, Q1 = 15.6208 s, Median = 15.6239 s, Q3 = 15.6304 s, Max = 15.6417 s
IQR = 0.0097 s, LowerFence = 15.6062 s, UpperFence = 15.6450 s
ConfidenceInterval = [15.6164 s; 15.6346 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.0091 s (0.06% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.66, Kurtosis = 2.36, MValue = 2

// **************************
// Benchmark: Paralleling.AllSequential: Core(Runtime=Core)
// *** Execute ***
// Launch: 1 / 1
// Execute: dotnet "e6babe6d-16ff-42cd-aa3e-d457250f812c.dll" --benchmarkName "ConsoleApp.Program+Paralleling.AllSequential" --job "Core" --benchmarkId 1 in C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\Playground\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\bin\Release\ne
tcoreapp2.2\e6babe6d-16ff-42cd-aa3e-d457250f812c\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2
// BeforeAnythingElse

// Benchmark Process Environment Information:
// Runtime=.NET Core 2.2.3 (CoreCLR 4.6.27414.05, CoreFX 4.6.27414.05), 64bit RyuJIT
// GC=Concurrent Workstation
// Job: Core(Runtime=Core)

OverheadJitting  1: 1 op, 313300.00 ns, 313.3000 us/op
WorkloadJitting  1: 1 op, 15627659000.00 ns, 15.6277 s/op

WorkloadWarmup   1: 1 op, 15618290800.00 ns, 15.6183 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   2: 1 op, 15615060100.00 ns, 15.6151 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   3: 1 op, 15640535400.00 ns, 15.6405 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   4: 1 op, 15627643200.00 ns, 15.6276 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   5: 1 op, 15618477200.00 ns, 15.6185 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   6: 1 op, 15630480200.00 ns, 15.6305 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   7: 1 op, 15618496000.00 ns, 15.6185 s/op

// BeforeActualRun
WorkloadActual   1: 1 op, 15643436500.00 ns, 15.6434 s/op
WorkloadActual   2: 1 op, 15633023800.00 ns, 15.6330 s/op
WorkloadActual   3: 1 op, 15622361000.00 ns, 15.6224 s/op
WorkloadActual   4: 1 op, 15624673600.00 ns, 15.6247 s/op
WorkloadActual   5: 1 op, 15622833000.00 ns, 15.6228 s/op
WorkloadActual   6: 1 op, 15631459600.00 ns, 15.6315 s/op
WorkloadActual   7: 1 op, 15637421400.00 ns, 15.6374 s/op
WorkloadActual   8: 1 op, 15623196600.00 ns, 15.6232 s/op
WorkloadActual   9: 1 op, 15640573100.00 ns, 15.6406 s/op
WorkloadActual  10: 1 op, 15621312000.00 ns, 15.6213 s/op
WorkloadActual  11: 1 op, 15633047100.00 ns, 15.6330 s/op
WorkloadActual  12: 1 op, 15624742400.00 ns, 15.6247 s/op
WorkloadActual  13: 1 op, 15626075700.00 ns, 15.6261 s/op
WorkloadActual  14: 1 op, 15622062500.00 ns, 15.6221 s/op
WorkloadActual  15: 1 op, 15627008400.00 ns, 15.6270 s/op

// AfterActualRun
WorkloadResult   1: 1 op, 15643436500.00 ns, 15.6434 s/op
WorkloadResult   2: 1 op, 15633023800.00 ns, 15.6330 s/op
WorkloadResult   3: 1 op, 15622361000.00 ns, 15.6224 s/op
WorkloadResult   4: 1 op, 15624673600.00 ns, 15.6247 s/op
WorkloadResult   5: 1 op, 15622833000.00 ns, 15.6228 s/op
WorkloadResult   6: 1 op, 15631459600.00 ns, 15.6315 s/op
WorkloadResult   7: 1 op, 15637421400.00 ns, 15.6374 s/op
WorkloadResult   8: 1 op, 15623196600.00 ns, 15.6232 s/op
WorkloadResult   9: 1 op, 15640573100.00 ns, 15.6406 s/op
WorkloadResult  10: 1 op, 15621312000.00 ns, 15.6213 s/op
WorkloadResult  11: 1 op, 15633047100.00 ns, 15.6330 s/op
WorkloadResult  12: 1 op, 15624742400.00 ns, 15.6247 s/op
WorkloadResult  13: 1 op, 15626075700.00 ns, 15.6261 s/op
WorkloadResult  14: 1 op, 15622062500.00 ns, 15.6221 s/op
WorkloadResult  15: 1 op, 15627008400.00 ns, 15.6270 s/op
GC:  0 0 0 0 0

// AfterAll

Mean = 15.6289 s, StdErr = 0.0019 s (0.01%); N = 15, StdDev = 0.0072 s
Min = 15.6213 s, Q1 = 15.6228 s, Median = 15.6261 s, Q3 = 15.6330 s, Max = 15.6434 s
IQR = 0.0102 s, LowerFence = 15.6075 s, UpperFence = 15.6484 s
ConfidenceInterval = [15.6212 s; 15.6366 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.0077 s (0.05% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.69, Kurtosis = 1.99, MValue = 2

Successfully reverted power plan (GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c FriendlyName: High performance)
// ***** BenchmarkRunner: Finish  *****

// * Export *
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\ConsoleApp.Program.Paralleling-report.csv
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\ConsoleApp.Program.Paralleling-report-github.md
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\ConsoleApp.Program.Paralleling-report.html
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\ConsoleApp.Program.Paralleling-measurements.csv
  BuildPlots.R
RPlotExporter couldn't find Rscript.exe in your PATH and no R_HOME environment variable is defined

// * Detailed results *
Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential: Core(Runtime=Core)
Runtime = .NET Core 2.2.3 (CoreCLR 4.6.27414.05, CoreFX 4.6.27414.05), 64bit RyuJIT; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 15.6255 s, StdErr = 0.0022 s (0.01%); N = 14, StdDev = 0.0081 s
Min = 15.6146 s, Q1 = 15.6208 s, Median = 15.6239 s, Q3 = 15.6304 s, Max = 15.6417 s
IQR = 0.0097 s, LowerFence = 15.6062 s, UpperFence = 15.6450 s
ConfidenceInterval = [15.6164 s; 15.6346 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.0091 s (0.06% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.66, Kurtosis = 2.36, MValue = 2
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[15.612 s ; 15.645 s) | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@
---------------------------------------------------

Paralleling.AllSequential: Core(Runtime=Core)
Runtime = .NET Core 2.2.3 (CoreCLR 4.6.27414.05, CoreFX 4.6.27414.05), 64bit RyuJIT; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 15.6289 s, StdErr = 0.0019 s (0.01%); N = 15, StdDev = 0.0072 s
Min = 15.6213 s, Q1 = 15.6228 s, Median = 15.6261 s, Q3 = 15.6330 s, Max = 15.6434 s
IQR = 0.0102 s, LowerFence = 15.6075 s, UpperFence = 15.6484 s
ConfidenceInterval = [15.6212 s; 15.6366 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.0077 s (0.05% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.69, Kurtosis = 1.99, MValue = 2
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[15.619 s ; 15.646 s) | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
---------------------------------------------------

// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.17134.407 (1803/April2018Update/Redstone4)
Intel Core i7-7820HQ CPU 2.90GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=2.2.202
  [Host] : .NET Core 2.2.3 (CoreCLR 4.6.27414.05, CoreFX 4.6.27414.05), 64bit RyuJIT
  Core   : .NET Core 2.2.3 (CoreCLR 4.6.27414.05, CoreFX 4.6.27414.05), 64bit RyuJIT

Job=Core  Runtime=Core  

|                Method |    Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Rank |
|---------------------- |--------:|---------:|---------:|-----:|
| ParallelAndSequential | 15.63 s | 0.0091 s | 0.0081 s |    1 |
|         AllSequential | 15.63 s | 0.0077 s | 0.0072 s |    1 |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential: Core -> 1 outlier  was  removed (15.66 s)

// * Legends *
  Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
  Rank   : Relative position of current benchmark mean among all benchmarks (Arabic style)
  1 s    : 1 Second (1 sec)

// ***** BenchmarkRunner: End *****
// ** Remained 0 benchmark(s) to run **
Run time: 00:11:44 (704.57 sec), executed benchmarks: 2

Global total time: 00:11:50 (710.04 sec), executed benchmarks: 2
// * Artifacts cleanup *

Process finished with exit code 0.
```

I don't really get why the `Parallel.ForEach` is not faster than the whole sequential strategy, is it because the `BlockingCollection` is the actual bottleneck?

Is there another strategy to better leverage `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: If you've not got any side effects in the bits you're running with `Parallel.ForEach`, have you considered using PLINQ instead?

Comment: You should spawn enough ThreadPoll threads before the processing. Take a look [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3008250/understanding-thread-pools-in-c.html). Creating them on the fly takes longer than processing. Also, there are some parameters for Parallel.ForEach that you should setup: max concurent threads is one of them.

Comment: Why the `await Task.Delay(10);`? Looks like a good place to increase speed.

Comment: `Parallel.For`xxx is kinda pointless when mixed with I/O, the former is designed for _compute operations_ where explicit threads are used for each concurrent line.  You don't want a thread waiting on I/O.  You may want to consider using the _TPL DataFlow_ library instead.  It allows you to combine both.  By the way, **don't** use `Task.Run`, `async/await` in conjunction with `Parallel.For`xxx.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach

Comment: Hi folks, mind telling me why my question has been downvoted so many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to follow the recommendation to leverage [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) as well as refactoring my sample code to put more emphasis on the CPU-bound (basically a good old `Thread.Sleep`).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static void ForEach<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> action)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                action(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        [ClrJob]
        [RPlotExporter, RankColumn]
        public class Paralleling
        {
            private IEnumerable<int> _items;

            [GlobalSetup]
            public void Setup()
            {
                _items = Enumerable.Range(0, 5000);
            }

            private bool GetMeALongCpuBool(int number)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                return number % 2 == 0;
            }

            [Benchmark]
            public async Task DataFlow()
            {
                var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, (bool, int, int)>(item =>
                {
                    var dummy = GetMeALongCpuBool(item);
                    return (dummy, item, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
                });

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
                {
                    var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<(bool, int, int)>(async result =>
                    await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(result.ToString()));

                    transformBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                    {
                        PropagateCompletion = true
                    });

                    _items.ForEach(async item => await transformBlock.SendAsync(item));

                    transformBlock.Complete();

                    await actionBlock.Completion;
                }
            }


            [Benchmark]
            public async Task ParallelAndSequential()
            {
                var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<(bool, int, int)>();

                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(_items, item =>
                    {
                        var dummy = GetMeALongCpuBool(item);
                        blockingCollection.Add((dummy, item, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                    });
                    blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
                });

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
                {
                    foreach (var result in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    {
                        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(result.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            [Benchmark]
            public async Task AllSequential()
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
                {
                    foreach (var item in _items)
                    {
                        var dummy = GetMeALongCpuBool(item);
                        var result = (dummy, item, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(result.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Main(params string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Paralleling>();
        }
    }
}
```

For some reasons it seems that this time the `Parallel.ForEach` is the fastest option followed by the Dataflow(maybe the actor system behind the scenes added some overhead but it provides a smoother integration with `async`/`await`) which seems to be still a little bit more aggressive than just using `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable` which posses a relatively simple [implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs#L1670).

In both cases (`Parallel.ForEach` and Dataflow), (they) are still much faster than the plain sequential old way, which is what I was expecting initially.

New benchmark results are right below:

```
// Validating benchmarks:
// ***** BenchmarkRunner: Start   *****
// ***** Found 3 benchmark(s) in total *****
// ***** Building 1 exe(s) in Parallel: Start   *****
BuildScript: C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\Playground\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\bin\Release\net472\34fab948-1750-4a20-832f-c235d6c6b967.bat
// ***** Done, took 00:00:03 (3.47 sec)   *****
// Found 3 benchmarks:
//   Paralleling.DataFlow: Clr(Runtime=Clr)
//   Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential: Clr(Runtime=Clr)
//   Paralleling.AllSequential: Clr(Runtime=Clr)

Setup power plan (GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c FriendlyName: High performance)// **************************
// Benchmark: Paralleling.DataFlow: Clr(Runtime=Clr)
// *** Execute ***
// Launch: 1 / 1
// Execute: C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\Playground\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\bin\Release\net472\34fab948-1750-4a20-832f-c235d6c6b967.exe --b
enchmarkName "ConsoleApp.Program+Paralleling.DataFlow" --job "Clr" --benchmarkId 0 in 
// BeforeAnythingElse

// Benchmark Process Environment Information:
// Runtime=.NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3221.0
// GC=Concurrent Workstation
// Job: Clr(Runtime=Clr)

OverheadJitting  1: 1 op, 301500.00 ns, 301.5000 us/op
WorkloadJitting  1: 1 op, 6766114100.00 ns, 6.7661 s/op

WorkloadWarmup   1: 1 op, 6684374600.00 ns, 6.6844 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   2: 1 op, 6741597000.00 ns, 6.7416 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   3: 1 op, 6678205800.00 ns, 6.6782 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   4: 1 op, 6694086900.00 ns, 6.6941 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   5: 1 op, 6725310100.00 ns, 6.7253 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   6: 1 op, 6739073300.00 ns, 6.7391 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   7: 1 op, 6701728400.00 ns, 6.7017 s/op

// BeforeActualRun
WorkloadActual   1: 1 op, 6739354900.00 ns, 6.7394 s/op
WorkloadActual   2: 1 op, 6705538000.00 ns, 6.7055 s/op
WorkloadActual   3: 1 op, 6705645700.00 ns, 6.7056 s/op
WorkloadActual   4: 1 op, 6734594900.00 ns, 6.7346 s/op
WorkloadActual   5: 1 op, 6687179600.00 ns, 6.6872 s/op
WorkloadActual   6: 1 op, 6681016900.00 ns, 6.6810 s/op
WorkloadActual   7: 1 op, 6708053800.00 ns, 6.7081 s/op
WorkloadActual   8: 1 op, 6703350900.00 ns, 6.7034 s/op
WorkloadActual   9: 1 op, 6709533800.00 ns, 6.7095 s/op
WorkloadActual  10: 1 op, 6742676000.00 ns, 6.7427 s/op
WorkloadActual  11: 1 op, 6710231600.00 ns, 6.7102 s/op
WorkloadActual  12: 1 op, 6695547000.00 ns, 6.6955 s/op
WorkloadActual  13: 1 op, 6708751300.00 ns, 6.7088 s/op
WorkloadActual  14: 1 op, 6731132100.00 ns, 6.7311 s/op
WorkloadActual  15: 1 op, 6828591700.00 ns, 6.8286 s/op

// AfterActualRun
WorkloadResult   1: 1 op, 6739354900.00 ns, 6.7394 s/op
WorkloadResult   2: 1 op, 6705538000.00 ns, 6.7055 s/op
WorkloadResult   3: 1 op, 6705645700.00 ns, 6.7056 s/op
WorkloadResult   4: 1 op, 6734594900.00 ns, 6.7346 s/op
WorkloadResult   5: 1 op, 6687179600.00 ns, 6.6872 s/op
WorkloadResult   6: 1 op, 6681016900.00 ns, 6.6810 s/op
WorkloadResult   7: 1 op, 6708053800.00 ns, 6.7081 s/op
WorkloadResult   8: 1 op, 6703350900.00 ns, 6.7034 s/op
WorkloadResult   9: 1 op, 6709533800.00 ns, 6.7095 s/op
WorkloadResult  10: 1 op, 6742676000.00 ns, 6.7427 s/op
WorkloadResult  11: 1 op, 6710231600.00 ns, 6.7102 s/op
WorkloadResult  12: 1 op, 6695547000.00 ns, 6.6955 s/op
WorkloadResult  13: 1 op, 6708751300.00 ns, 6.7088 s/op
WorkloadResult  14: 1 op, 6731132100.00 ns, 6.7311 s/op
GC:  0 0 0 0 0

// AfterAll

Mean = 6.7116 s, StdErr = 0.0050 s (0.07%); N = 14, StdDev = 0.0188 s
Min = 6.6810 s, Q1 = 6.7034 s, Median = 6.7084 s, Q3 = 6.7311 s, Max = 6.7427 s
IQR = 0.0278 s, LowerFence = 6.6617 s, UpperFence = 6.7728 s
ConfidenceInterval = [6.6904 s; 6.7328 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.0212 s (0.32% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.24, Kurtosis = 1.85, MValue = 2

// **************************
// Benchmark: Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential: Clr(Runtime=Clr)
// *** Execute ***
// Launch: 1 / 1
// Execute: C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\Playground\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\bin\Release\net472\34fab948-1750-4a20-832f-c235d6c6b967.exe --b
enchmarkName "ConsoleApp.Program+Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential" --job "Clr" --benchmarkId 1 in 
// BeforeAnythingElse

// Benchmark Process Environment Information:
// Runtime=.NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3221.0
// GC=Concurrent Workstation
// Job: Clr(Runtime=Clr)

OverheadJitting  1: 1 op, 374800.00 ns, 374.8000 us/op
WorkloadJitting  1: 1 op, 6956299700.00 ns, 6.9563 s/op

WorkloadWarmup   1: 1 op, 6046076100.00 ns, 6.0461 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   2: 1 op, 6852625900.00 ns, 6.8526 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   3: 1 op, 5474965800.00 ns, 5.4750 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   4: 1 op, 5473499200.00 ns, 5.4735 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   5: 1 op, 5518366900.00 ns, 5.5184 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   6: 1 op, 6859923700.00 ns, 6.8599 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   7: 1 op, 6862675600.00 ns, 6.8627 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   8: 1 op, 5536335800.00 ns, 5.5363 s/op

// BeforeActualRun
WorkloadActual   1: 1 op, 5528208700.00 ns, 5.5282 s/op
WorkloadActual   2: 1 op, 5519601400.00 ns, 5.5196 s/op
WorkloadActual   3: 1 op, 5500471200.00 ns, 5.5005 s/op
WorkloadActual   4: 1 op, 5539328200.00 ns, 5.5393 s/op
WorkloadActual   5: 1 op, 5465452200.00 ns, 5.4655 s/op
WorkloadActual   6: 1 op, 5470452100.00 ns, 5.4705 s/op
WorkloadActual   7: 1 op, 5512168300.00 ns, 5.5122 s/op
WorkloadActual   8: 1 op, 5472912400.00 ns, 5.4729 s/op
WorkloadActual   9: 1 op, 5855563000.00 ns, 5.8556 s/op
WorkloadActual  10: 1 op, 5992147700.00 ns, 5.9921 s/op
WorkloadActual  11: 1 op, 6143075000.00 ns, 6.1431 s/op
WorkloadActual  12: 1 op, 6397675600.00 ns, 6.3977 s/op
WorkloadActual  13: 1 op, 6909029100.00 ns, 6.9090 s/op
WorkloadActual  14: 1 op, 5525335600.00 ns, 5.5253 s/op
WorkloadActual  15: 1 op, 5470029700.00 ns, 5.4700 s/op
WorkloadActual  16: 1 op, 5481800300.00 ns, 5.4818 s/op
WorkloadActual  17: 1 op, 5507468600.00 ns, 5.5075 s/op
WorkloadActual  18: 1 op, 5465031900.00 ns, 5.4650 s/op
WorkloadActual  19: 1 op, 5478785200.00 ns, 5.4788 s/op
WorkloadActual  20: 1 op, 5511074600.00 ns, 5.5111 s/op
WorkloadActual  21: 1 op, 6080651400.00 ns, 6.0807 s/op
WorkloadActual  22: 1 op, 6829810900.00 ns, 6.8298 s/op
WorkloadActual  23: 1 op, 6878471900.00 ns, 6.8785 s/op
WorkloadActual  24: 1 op, 5506067800.00 ns, 5.5061 s/op
WorkloadActual  25: 1 op, 5442596200.00 ns, 5.4426 s/op
WorkloadActual  26: 1 op, 5463614300.00 ns, 5.4636 s/op
WorkloadActual  27: 1 op, 5491205500.00 ns, 5.4912 s/op
WorkloadActual  28: 1 op, 5482997900.00 ns, 5.4830 s/op
WorkloadActual  29: 1 op, 5494967800.00 ns, 5.4950 s/op
WorkloadActual  30: 1 op, 5517805900.00 ns, 5.5178 s/op
WorkloadActual  31: 1 op, 5486377000.00 ns, 5.4864 s/op

// AfterActualRun
WorkloadResult   1: 1 op, 5528208700.00 ns, 5.5282 s/op
WorkloadResult   2: 1 op, 5519601400.00 ns, 5.5196 s/op
WorkloadResult   3: 1 op, 5500471200.00 ns, 5.5005 s/op
WorkloadResult   4: 1 op, 5539328200.00 ns, 5.5393 s/op
WorkloadResult   5: 1 op, 5465452200.00 ns, 5.4655 s/op
WorkloadResult   6: 1 op, 5470452100.00 ns, 5.4705 s/op
WorkloadResult   7: 1 op, 5512168300.00 ns, 5.5122 s/op
WorkloadResult   8: 1 op, 5472912400.00 ns, 5.4729 s/op
WorkloadResult   9: 1 op, 5855563000.00 ns, 5.8556 s/op
WorkloadResult  10: 1 op, 5992147700.00 ns, 5.9921 s/op
WorkloadResult  11: 1 op, 6143075000.00 ns, 6.1431 s/op
WorkloadResult  12: 1 op, 6397675600.00 ns, 6.3977 s/op
WorkloadResult  13: 1 op, 5525335600.00 ns, 5.5253 s/op
WorkloadResult  14: 1 op, 5470029700.00 ns, 5.4700 s/op
WorkloadResult  15: 1 op, 5481800300.00 ns, 5.4818 s/op
WorkloadResult  16: 1 op, 5507468600.00 ns, 5.5075 s/op
WorkloadResult  17: 1 op, 5465031900.00 ns, 5.4650 s/op
WorkloadResult  18: 1 op, 5478785200.00 ns, 5.4788 s/op
WorkloadResult  19: 1 op, 5511074600.00 ns, 5.5111 s/op
WorkloadResult  20: 1 op, 6080651400.00 ns, 6.0807 s/op
WorkloadResult  21: 1 op, 5506067800.00 ns, 5.5061 s/op
WorkloadResult  22: 1 op, 5442596200.00 ns, 5.4426 s/op
WorkloadResult  23: 1 op, 5463614300.00 ns, 5.4636 s/op
WorkloadResult  24: 1 op, 5491205500.00 ns, 5.4912 s/op
WorkloadResult  25: 1 op, 5482997900.00 ns, 5.4830 s/op
WorkloadResult  26: 1 op, 5494967800.00 ns, 5.4950 s/op
WorkloadResult  27: 1 op, 5517805900.00 ns, 5.5178 s/op
WorkloadResult  28: 1 op, 5486377000.00 ns, 5.4864 s/op
GC:  0 0 0 0 0

// AfterAll

Mean = 5.6001 s, StdErr = 0.0469 s (0.84%); N = 28, StdDev = 0.2479 s
Min = 5.4426 s, Q1 = 5.4758 s, Median = 5.5033 s, Q3 = 5.5268 s, Max = 6.3977 s
IQR = 0.0509 s, LowerFence = 5.3995 s, UpperFence = 5.6032 s
ConfidenceInterval = [5.4272 s; 5.7730 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.1729 s (3.09% of Mean)
Skewness = 1.93, Kurtosis = 5.45, MValue = 2

// **************************
// Benchmark: Paralleling.AllSequential: Clr(Runtime=Clr)
// *** Execute ***
// Launch: 1 / 1
// Execute: C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\Playground\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\bin\Release\net472\34fab948-1750-4a20-832f-c235d6c6b967.exe -
-benchmarkName "ConsoleApp.Program+Paralleling.AllSequential" --job "Clr" --benchmarkId 2 in 
// BeforeAnythingElse

// Benchmark Process Environment Information:
// Runtime=.NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3221.0
// GC=Concurrent Workstation
// Job: Clr(Runtime=Clr)

OverheadJitting  1: 1 op, 293200.00 ns, 293.2000 us/op
WorkloadJitting  1: 1 op, 53809888100.00 ns, 53.8099 s/op

WorkloadWarmup   1: 1 op, 53587422400.00 ns, 53.5874 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   2: 1 op, 53646293300.00 ns, 53.6463 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   3: 1 op, 53664071000.00 ns, 53.6641 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   4: 1 op, 53565564100.00 ns, 53.5656 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   5: 1 op, 53753653900.00 ns, 53.7537 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   6: 1 op, 53765022400.00 ns, 53.7650 s/op
WorkloadWarmup   7: 1 op, 53548369900.00 ns, 53.5484 s/op

// BeforeActualRun
WorkloadActual   1: 1 op, 53571559600.00 ns, 53.5716 s/op
WorkloadActual   2: 1 op, 53777716600.00 ns, 53.7777 s/op
WorkloadActual   3: 1 op, 53634262000.00 ns, 53.6343 s/op
WorkloadActual   4: 1 op, 53555998800.00 ns, 53.5560 s/op
WorkloadActual   5: 1 op, 53529152600.00 ns, 53.5292 s/op
WorkloadActual   6: 1 op, 53609217000.00 ns, 53.6092 s/op
WorkloadActual   7: 1 op, 53511316400.00 ns, 53.5113 s/op
WorkloadActual   8: 1 op, 53246673500.00 ns, 53.2467 s/op
WorkloadActual   9: 1 op, 53770915500.00 ns, 53.7709 s/op
WorkloadActual  10: 1 op, 54462781200.00 ns, 54.4628 s/op
WorkloadActual  11: 1 op, 54111001500.00 ns, 54.1110 s/op
WorkloadActual  12: 1 op, 54194051600.00 ns, 54.1941 s/op
WorkloadActual  13: 1 op, 53924013600.00 ns, 53.9240 s/op
WorkloadActual  14: 1 op, 53855213500.00 ns, 53.8552 s/op
WorkloadActual  15: 1 op, 53919584800.00 ns, 53.9196 s/op

// AfterActualRun
WorkloadResult   1: 1 op, 53571559600.00 ns, 53.5716 s/op
WorkloadResult   2: 1 op, 53777716600.00 ns, 53.7777 s/op
WorkloadResult   3: 1 op, 53634262000.00 ns, 53.6343 s/op
WorkloadResult   4: 1 op, 53555998800.00 ns, 53.5560 s/op
WorkloadResult   5: 1 op, 53529152600.00 ns, 53.5292 s/op
WorkloadResult   6: 1 op, 53609217000.00 ns, 53.6092 s/op
WorkloadResult   7: 1 op, 53511316400.00 ns, 53.5113 s/op
WorkloadResult   8: 1 op, 53246673500.00 ns, 53.2467 s/op
WorkloadResult   9: 1 op, 53770915500.00 ns, 53.7709 s/op
WorkloadResult  10: 1 op, 54462781200.00 ns, 54.4628 s/op
WorkloadResult  11: 1 op, 54111001500.00 ns, 54.1110 s/op
WorkloadResult  12: 1 op, 54194051600.00 ns, 54.1941 s/op
WorkloadResult  13: 1 op, 53924013600.00 ns, 53.9240 s/op
WorkloadResult  14: 1 op, 53855213500.00 ns, 53.8552 s/op
WorkloadResult  15: 1 op, 53919584800.00 ns, 53.9196 s/op
GC:  0 0 0 0 0

// AfterAll

Mean = 53.7782 s, StdErr = 0.0804 s (0.15%); N = 15, StdDev = 0.3113 s
Min = 53.2467 s, Q1 = 53.5560 s, Median = 53.7709 s, Q3 = 53.9240 s, Max = 54.4628 s
IQR = 0.3680 s, LowerFence = 53.0040 s, UpperFence = 54.4760 s
ConfidenceInterval = [53.4454 s; 54.1110 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.3328 s (0.62% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.49, Kurtosis = 2.53, MValue = 2

Successfully reverted power plan (GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c FriendlyName: High performance)
// ***** BenchmarkRunner: Finish  *****

// * Export *
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\ConsoleApp.Program.Paralleling-report.csv
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\ConsoleApp.Program.Paralleling-report-github.md
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\ConsoleApp.Program.Paralleling-report.html
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\ConsoleApp.Program.Paralleling-measurements.csv
  BuildPlots.R
RPlotExporter couldn't find Rscript.exe in your PATH and no R_HOME environment variable is defined

// * Detailed results *
Paralleling.DataFlow: Clr(Runtime=Clr)
Runtime = .NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3221.0; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 6.7116 s, StdErr = 0.0050 s (0.07%); N = 14, StdDev = 0.0188 s
Min = 6.6810 s, Q1 = 6.7034 s, Median = 6.7084 s, Q3 = 6.7311 s, Max = 6.7427 s
IQR = 0.0278 s, LowerFence = 6.6617 s, UpperFence = 6.7728 s
ConfidenceInterval = [6.6904 s; 6.7328 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.0212 s (0.32% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.24, Kurtosis = 1.85, MValue = 2
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[6.674 s ; 6.750 s) | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@
---------------------------------------------------

Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential: Clr(Runtime=Clr)
Runtime = .NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3221.0; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 5.6001 s, StdErr = 0.0469 s (0.84%); N = 28, StdDev = 0.2479 s
Min = 5.4426 s, Q1 = 5.4758 s, Median = 5.5033 s, Q3 = 5.5268 s, Max = 6.3977 s
IQR = 0.0509 s, LowerFence = 5.3995 s, UpperFence = 5.6032 s
ConfidenceInterval = [5.4272 s; 5.7730 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.1729 s (3.09% of Mean)
Skewness = 1.93, Kurtosis = 5.45, MValue = 2
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[5.420 s ; 5.562 s) | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[5.562 s ; 5.705 s) | 
[5.705 s ; 5.852 s) | 
[5.852 s ; 5.995 s) | @@
[5.995 s ; 6.183 s) | @@
[6.183 s ; 6.326 s) | 
[6.326 s ; 6.469 s) | @
---------------------------------------------------

Paralleling.AllSequential: Clr(Runtime=Clr)
Runtime = .NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3221.0; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 53.7782 s, StdErr = 0.0804 s (0.15%); N = 15, StdDev = 0.3113 s
Min = 53.2467 s, Q1 = 53.5560 s, Median = 53.7709 s, Q3 = 53.9240 s, Max = 54.4628 s
IQR = 0.3680 s, LowerFence = 53.0040 s, UpperFence = 54.4760 s
ConfidenceInterval = [53.4454 s; 54.1110 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.3328 s (0.62% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.49, Kurtosis = 2.53, MValue = 2
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[53.136 s ; 54.573 s) | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
---------------------------------------------------

// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.17134.407 (1803/April2018Update/Redstone4)
Intel Core i7-7820HQ CPU 2.90GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
  [Host] : .NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3221.0
  Clr    : .NET Framework 4.7.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3221.0

Job=Clr  Runtime=Clr  

|                Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Rank |
|---------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|-----:|
|              DataFlow |  6.712 s | 0.0212 s | 0.0188 s |    2 |
| ParallelAndSequential |  5.600 s | 0.1729 s | 0.2479 s |    1 |
|         AllSequential | 53.778 s | 0.3328 s | 0.3113 s |    3 |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  Paralleling.DataFlow: Clr              -> 1 outlier  was  removed (6.83 s)
  Paralleling.ParallelAndSequential: Clr -> 3 outliers were removed (6.83 s..6.91 s)

// * Legends *
  Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
  Rank   : Relative position of current benchmark mean among all benchmarks (Arabic style)
  1 s    : 1 Second (1 sec)

// ***** BenchmarkRunner: End *****
// ** Remained 0 benchmark(s) to run **
Run time: 00:27:06 (1626.41 sec), executed benchmarks: 3

Global total time: 00:27:09 (1629.9 sec), executed benchmarks: 3
// * Artifacts cleanup *
```

Answer (score 1):

Your times suggest that there writing to memory is the main time consuming thing. It would go nicely with the fact, that my processor during the runs barely got to 20% of utilization. When you comment out the `stream.WriteLine` you can see, that the tasks are way to short to make use of parallelisation:

```
|                Method |      Mean |      Error |   StdDev | Rank |
|---------------------- |----------:|-----------:|---------:|-----:|
| ParallelAndSequential | 564.50 us | 1,759.4 us | 96.44 us |    2 |
|         AllSequential |  54.31 us |   400.0 us | 21.92 us |    1 |
```

Good idea is to profile your app if you feel that it is slow, even before writing benchmarks. It will show which part/line is a bottleneck

Answer (score 1):

There are many things going on here.

1. The workload is imbalanced. The writing to the stream is more than 90% of the job, and is not parallelized. Maybe is not even parallelizable.
2. The embedded Task.Delays are skewing the results.
3. The workload is too granular. The `BlockingCollection` becomes a point of contention.
4. The `BlockingCollection` is not upper-bounded, which combined with the small workload of the CPU-bound tasks means that almost all the output is buffered in the `BlockingCollection` before being consumed by the IO-bound task, causing large memory allocation.
5. The awaitings are not configured with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, causing multiple context captures and restorations.
6. The `Parallel.ForEach` has not be configured with the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option, exaggerating the imbalance of the workload. All the processors of the machine are tasked with CPU-bound tasks, leaving none free for the single IO-bound task.

After making some changes to the configuration I achieved results that favor the `ParallelAndSequential` approach over the `AllSequential` approach, on a ratio of ~2/5.

```
_items = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);
Ackermann(m: 3, n: 6);
var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<(bool, int, int)>(boundedCapacity: 10);
await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(result.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
//await Task.Delay(10);
new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1};
```