# How after completing any task in the loop, pass a value to another method, return to the loop, and wait for the next task to complete?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, webrequest

There are **2 methods**, **one method depends on the other**. I need to send several files to the server in parallel, which answer from the server comes first, and send it to `DownloadFileAsync` method, and do the same with the rest (without waiting for all answers at once, send them (answers from the server) to `DownloadFileAsync()` method, as they are received).

```
public async Task CompressAllFilesAsync(List<UserFile> files, string outputpath)
{
    await UploadAllFilesAsync(files);
    await DownloadAllFilesAsync(files, outputpath);
}

public async Task UploadAllFilesAsync(List<UserFile> files)
{
    IEnumerable<Task> allTasks = files.Select(async (file, i) =>
        files[i].FileLink = await UploadFileAsync(files[i])
    );

    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}

public async Task DownloadAllFilesAsync(List<UserFile> files, string outputpath)
{
    IEnumerable<Task> allTasks = files.Select((file, i) =>
        DownloadFileAsync(files[i].FileLink,
        Path.Combine(outputpath, $"{files[i].FileName}")
    ));

    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}
```

Now the program is waiting for all answers from the server (links to downloadable files) before running the `DownloadAllFilesAsync()` method.

[image: Image-Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using the new (.NET 6) API [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync), and execute the `UploadFileAsync` and then the `DownloadFileAsync` sequentially for each `UserFile`, but concurrently with other files:

```
public async Task CompressAllFilesAsync(List<UserFile> files, string outputPath)
{
    var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(files, options, async (file, ct) =>
    {
        await UploadFileAsync(file);
        await DownloadFileAsync(file.FileLink,
            Path.Combine(outputPath, $"{file.FileName}"));
    });
}
```

The `UploadFileAsync` and `DownloadFileAsync` will be invoked on `ThreadPool` threads. This shouldn't be a problem, unless those methods interact with thread-affine components (like UI controls).

Comment: What is "ct" inside "async (file, ct)"?

Comment: @Ilya it's a `CancellationToken`, that you could use to cancel the processing of one file, if another file failed (for faster propagation of the error). It seems that your `UploadFileAsync` and `DownloadFileAsync` methods are not cancelable, so you can't pass this token to them, but you might consider intercepting a `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` between the two calls.

Comment: I can't seem to use "Parallel.ForEachAsync", in Visual Studio 2017 with "Target Platform 4.6.1", this method is not available.

Comment: @Ilya can you download the Visual Studio 2022 and target the newest .NET 6 runtime? If not, then you can't use the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API. You'll have to find an alternative to this method (there are many custom implementations available), like the one that I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach/65251949#65251949).

Comment: Thank you for your help with the code, I managed to find another solution that does the same as your code and does not require (.NET 5 | 6).

Comment: @Ilya you're welcome! I preferred to show a solution that targets the latest .NET runtime, because it will be applicable to a larger audience in the long run. Using instead the `Task.WhenAll` and a `SemaphoreSlim` is a valid approach. It's a bit clumsy compared to the elegant `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
public async Task CompressAllFilesAsync(List<UserFile> files, string outputpath) {
    SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(2);

    IEnumerable<Task> allTasks = files.Select(async (file) => {
        await throttler.WaitAsync();

        try {
            file.Link = await UploadFileAsync(file);

            await DownloadFileAsync(file.Link,
                Path.Combine(outputpath, file.Name));
        } finally {
            throttler.Release();
        }
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileToSend; i++)
{    
   Task task = new Task(() => 
   {
      SendFile(file[i]);
   });
   task.Start();
}
```

This way you're gonna create a background task that will send your files in paralell

Comment: This solution didn't work, the DownloadFile() method gets the wrong data.

Comment: This code is roughly the same as `Task.Run()` without actually awaiting for the operation to complete. There's seldom any good reason for cold task that are explicitly started with `Start()`. A Task isn't a thread, it's a promise. Calling `Start()` will do the same thing as `Task.Run()`: schedule the promise for execution by a threadpool thread