# Parallel.ForEachAsync Task vs ValueTask

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-6.0, valuetask, parallel.foreachasync

I'm trying out `Parallel.ForEachAsync` and the compiler is kind enough to inform me that the body is a func that returns a `ValueTask`, not a `Task`.

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var numbers = Enumerable.Range(start: 0, count: 10);

// Error: 'Task WorkAsync(int, CancellationToken)' has the wrong return type
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    source: numbers,
    parallelOptions: new ParallelOptions{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 },
    body: WorkAsync); 

async Task WorkAsync(int item, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    WriteLine($"Task {item} Start");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    WriteLine($"Task {item} End");
}

void WriteLine(string s) => Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, 3} Thread{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {s}");
```

A quick search yielded only ForEachAsync examples that use a lambda with multiple statements: `async (x, ct) => { ...; await ...; }`.

I feel that

```
body: async (item, cancellationToken) => await WorkAsync(item, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

is significantly uglier than:

```
body: WorkAsync);
```

In the trivial example here I can obviously change the return type of the worker method, but it seems unwise to modify existing code to return `ValueTask`s.

Is there an obvious solution I have missed for creating beautiful code with `Parallel.ForEachAsync`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it qualifies as prettier, but you could consider doing this:

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    source: numbers,
    parallelOptions: new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 },
    body: ToValueTaskResult<int>(WorkAsync));

static Func<T, CancellationToken, ValueTask> ToValueTaskResult<T>(
    Func<T, CancellationToken, Task> function)
        => async (item, ct) => await function(item, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

To be honest I think that the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API would be better if it accepted a `Func<T, CancellationToken, Task>` delegate as the `body`, since the most common usage scenarios for this API are high latency I/O-bound operations over the network. For these scenarios, switching from `Task` to `ValueTask` makes practically zero difference, in either performance or memory-efficiency. Reducing the general usability of the API in order to optimize some exotic scenarios with [`IValueTaskSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.ivaluetasksource)-backed `body` delegates, makes little sense to me. But this is what we have now, and it's certainly much prettier than [what we had earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach), so I am not complaining too much.

Comment: I try to resist solutions like this, bu it is a very valid solution.