# Batched async API calls using .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

What is the recommended way to make async calls to external API in batches using C# from .NET Framework? The external API throttles the request if the number of calls exceeded a specific number.

How to make batched calls to an external API and then wait for the first batch to complete or wait x seconds before making the second batch of calls?

The reason for doing this is to avoid the external API throttling our calls. I know I can look at the retry-after header from the external API response header and then retry the requests when throttled but in this particular case I want to avoid being throttled due to specific reasons.

For example, let's say I want to make a total of 100 calls to the external API. I want to batch them into 20 API calls in 5 batches, such that each batch of 20 makes a request to the external API only after the previous batch has completed or after x seconds.

I tried `Task.WhenAll` but it makes all 100 API calls in one go. Since I want the calls to the external API to be async, I don't want to use `Parallel.ForEach` since it is synchronous, `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is not supported on the .NET framework.

The only solution I can think of is to use `Task.WhenAll` and make 20 requests at a time and then do `Task.Delay()` and then repeat calling `Task.WhenAll` until all the 100 requests are processed.

Is there a better way to handle this in the .NET Framework?

Comment: You can find a `Parallel.ForEachAsync` implementation for .NET Framework in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach/65251949#65251949 "Nesting await in Parallel.ForEach").

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)